# partial update to dataframe with Multi-index index with integer labels

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I am using multi index dataframe with mixed index labels i.e. first level contains string labels, 2nd and 3rd level are integer labels and 4th level labels are dates.
Dataframe looks like below (master_df)

```
                                           X1   X2  X3
bucket       Start    Stop       Date           
B1             1       1         1/3/2000   2   2   3
                                 1/4/2000   4   3   3
B1             1       2         1/3/2000   4   2   3
                                 1/4/2000   6   2   2
```

I want to take out sub_df as master_df.ix['B1',1,2,:], do some operations on sub_df and store it back into master_df at the same location. I am able to take out sub_df using various methods, but when comes to storing it back, all the options I have tried dont seem to be working. I guess this issue is related to having 'Integer' labels(at 2nd and 3rd lavel - start-stop). I have tried below options/methods without any success

```
    sub_df = master_df.ix['B1'].ix[1].ix[2]

    #do some operations on sub_df

    master_df.xs('B1').xs(1).xs(2).update(sub_df)

    master_df.ix['B1'].ix[1].ix[2].update(sub_df)

    merge(master_df.ix['B1',1,2,:],sub_df)
```

none of the above operations reflect changes in master_df (i dont get any error messages either.)

Can you suggest proper way to do it?

Update :

sub_df and master_df do not have same index as operations on sub_df expect date index only.
sub_df look like below.

```
          X1   X2  X3
Date           
1/3/2000   2   2   3
1/4/2000   4   3   3
```

If I try

```
sub_df = master_df[master_df.index.get_loc(('B1', 1, 2))]
```

I get following error -

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Main purpose here is to operate on only small chunk of master_df and store those results back at original location in master_df. I tried using update method, however any other alternative to achive this purpose will do.

Comment: could you check if `sub_df` has the same index as `master_df`? because the [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-together-values-within-series-or-dataframe-columns) mentions something like "two like-indexed (or similarly indexed)" DataFrames or Series for the `update` method.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly solve your question, but I this might
provide some inspiration

Here's a way to set the values directly

```
In [75]: df
Out[75]: 
  bucket  start  stop                date  x1  x2  x3
0     B1      1     1 2000-10-03 00:00:00   2   2   3
1     B1      1     1 2000-01-04 00:00:00   4   3   3
2     B1      1     2 2000-01-03 00:00:00   4   2   3
3     B1      1     2 2000-01-04 00:00:00   6   2   2

In [76]: df2 = df.set_index(['bucket','start','stop'])

In [77]: df2
Out[77]: 
                                 date  x1  x2  x3
bucket start stop                                
B1     1     1    2000-10-03 00:00:00   2   2   3
             1    2000-01-04 00:00:00   4   3   3
             2    2000-01-03 00:00:00   4   2   3
             2    2000-01-04 00:00:00   6   2   2

In [78]: df2.ix[('B1',1,2)].ix[:,'x1'] = 5

In [79]: df2
Out[79]: 
                                 date  x1  x2  x3
bucket start stop                                
B1     1     1    2000-10-03 00:00:00   2   2   3
             1    2000-01-04 00:00:00   4   3   3
             2    2000-01-03 00:00:00   5   2   3
             2    2000-01-04 00:00:00   5   2   2
```

Here's another way, where you select out a series that has a multi-index, modify it,
then assign it back (only works with series).

```
In [89]: df2.ix[:,'x1']
Out[89]: 
bucket  start  stop
B1      1      1       2
               1       4
               2       4
               2       6
Name: x1, dtype: int64

In [90]: new_s = df2.ix[:,'x1'].copy()

In [91]: new_s
Out[91]: 
bucket  start  stop
B1      1      1       2
               1       4
               2       4
               2       6
Name: x1, dtype: int64

# can also do a more complicated selctor than the 0th row
In [92]: new_s[0] = 5

In [93]: new_s
Out[93]: 
bucket  start  stop
B1      1      1       5
               1       4
               2       4
               2       6
Name: x1, dtype: int64

In [94]: df2.ix[:,'x1'] = new_s

In [95]: df2
Out[95]: 
                                 date  x1  x2  x3
bucket start stop                                
B1     1     1    2000-10-03 00:00:00   5   2   3
             1    2000-01-04 00:00:00   4   3   3
             2    2000-01-03 00:00:00   4   2   3
             2    2000-01-04 00:00:00   6   2   2
```

Here's what you can do in 0.11

```
# this is sessentially saying give me the first 2 rows (equivalent
# to selecting via complicated tuple)
In [107]: df2.iloc[0:2,:]
Out[107]: 
                                 date  x1  x2  x3
bucket start stop                                
B1     1     1    2000-10-03 00:00:00  10   2   3
             1    2000-01-04 00:00:00   4   3   3

In [108]: df2.iloc[0:2,:].loc[:,'x1']
Out[108]: 
bucket  start  stop
B1      1      1       10
               1        4
Name: x1, dtype: int64

In [109]: df2.iloc[0:2,:].loc[:,'x1'] = 5

In [110]: df2
Out[110]: 
                                 date  x1  x2  x3
bucket start stop                                
B1     1     1    2000-10-03 00:00:00   5   2   3
             1    2000-01-04 00:00:00   5   3   3
             2    2000-01-03 00:00:00   4   2   3
             2    2000-01-04 00:00:00   6   2   2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important that `sub_df` has the same index as `master_df`.

One way to get the correct index is to use `get_loc`:

```
sub_df = df[df.index.get_loc(('B1', 1, 2))]
# operations not changing index
master_df.update(sub_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help. At the end I switched to charater indexing from number indexing at level 2 and 3, and now things are working fine (this also helped in doing propering sorting on levels, which is i suppose made things more unambiguous.)

Answer (score 0):

For the example you give (selecting ('B1', 1, 2, ...)) you can use xs iso ix. In contrast to ix, xs can return a view on the data when using labels (more details on ix returning view/copy see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)).
In the example below, colum X1 of sub_df is changes, which also impacts master_df.

```
In [48]: master_df
Out[48]: 
                              X1  X2  X3
bucket Start Stop Date                  
B1     1     1    2000-01-03   2   2   3
                  2000-01-04   4   3   3
             2    2000-01-03   4   2   3
                  2000-01-04   6   2   2

In [49]: sub_df = master_df.xs(['B1', 1, 2], copy=False)

In [50]: sub_df
Out[50]: 
            X1  X2  X3
Date                  
2000-01-03   4   2   3
2000-01-04   6   2   2

In [51]: sub_df.X1 -= 4

In [52]: sub_df
Out[52]: 
            X1  X2  X3
Date                  
2000-01-03   0   2   3
2000-01-04   2   2   2

In [53]: master_df
Out[53]: 
                              X1  X2  X3
bucket Start Stop Date                  
B1     1     1    2000-01-03   2   2   3
                  2000-01-04   4   3   3
             2    2000-01-03   0   2   3
                  2000-01-04   2   2   2
```

Comment: Note: copy is no longer a parameter for .xs

Answer (score 0):

In 0.13 parameter 'drop_level' has been added to 'xs' so that will solve your problem as all index levels will be present in sub_df:

sub_df = master_df.xs(['B1', 1, 2], level=['bucket','Start','Stop'], drop_level=False)

Now merge will work.

Have not tried but it should work.

ref: ["Large data" work flows using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas)