# Python tools for out-of-core computation/data mining

Tags: python, numpy, data-mining, large-data, database

I am interested in `python mining` data sets too big to sit in RAM but sitting within a single HD.

I understand that I can export the data as `hdf5` files, using `pytables`. Also the `numexpr` allows for some basic out-of-core computation.

What would come next? Mini-batching when possible, and relying on linear algebra results to decompose the computation when mini-batching cannot be used?

Or are there some higher level tools I have missed?

Thanks for insights,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sklearn 0.14 (to be released in the coming days) there is a full-fledged example of out-of-core classification of text documents.

I think it could be a great example to start with :

http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html

In the next release we'll extend this example with more classifiers and add documentation in the user guide.

NB: you can reproduce this example with 0.13 too, all the building blocks were already there.

Answer (score 4):

What exactly do you want to do — can you give an example or two please ?

[numpy.memmap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) is easy —

> Create a memory-map to an array stored in a *binary* file on disk.
>   Memory-mapped files are used for accessing small segments of large
>   files on disk, without reading the entire file into memory.  Numpy's
>   memmap's are array-like objects ...

see also [numpy+memmap](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[numpy]+memmap) on SO.

The [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org) people are very knowledgeable, but prefer specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for answer Denis. It appears skilearn has mini-batching facilities. Actually I am looking for the most rational way to deal with out-of-the-core learning of a sub map-reduce size. Particularly I am striving to understand the relative strengths of hdf5, sql, nosql.

Comment: Zelazny7's large-data-work-flows question is better because concrete, and gets better answers

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar need to work on sub map-reduce sized datasets.  I posed this question on SO when I started to investigate python pandas as a serious alternative to SAS: ["Large data" work flows using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas)

The answer presented there suggests using the HDF5 interface from pandas to store pandas data structures directly on disk.  Once stored, you could access the data in batches and train a model incrementally.  For, example, scikit-learn has several classes that can be trained on incremental pieces of a dataset.  One such example is found here:

http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html

Any class that implements the `partial_fit` method can be trained incrementally.  I am still trying to get a viable workflow for these kinds of problems and would be interested in discussing possible solutions.