# appending rows with pandas' to_hdf multiples H5 file size?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, append, hdf5

I have an `HDF5` with about 13,000 rows × 5 columns, these rows were appended over time to the same file with `DF.to_hdf(Filename, 'df', append=True, format='table')` and here's the size:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 omnom  omnom   807M Mar 10 15:55 Final_all_result.h5
```

Recently I received a `ValueError` because the data I was trying to append to one of the columns is longer than the declared column size (2000, with `min_itemsize`).

So I loaded all rows to memory and dump these into a new `HDF` file **at one go** with:

```
DF.to_hdf(newFilename, \
                'df', \
                mode='a', \
                data_columns=['Code', 'ID', 'Category', 'Title', 'Content'], \
                format='table', \
                min_itemsize={'index': 24, \
                                'Code': 8, \
                                'ID': 32, \
                                'Category': 24, \
                                'Title': 192, \
                                'Content':5000 \
                                } \
                )
```

I was really surprised that the new file size is about 1/10 of the original file:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 omnom  omnom    70M Mar 10 16:01 Final_all_result_5000.h5
```

I double checked the number of rows in both files, they're equal.

Do I append new rows the wrong way that causes the file size to multiple with every append operation? Googled and searched here but don't think this was discussed before, or maybe I searched with the wrong keywords.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
I tried adding `min_itemsize` for all data columns in the append line per suggestion in this thread: [pandas pytables append: performance and increase in file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934996/pandas-pytables-append-performance-and-increase-in-file-size):

```
DF.to_hdf(h5AbsPath, \
                'df', \
                mode='a', \
                data_columns=['Code', 'ID', 'Category', 'Title', 'Content'], \
                min_itemsize={'index': 24, \
                                'Code': 8, \
                                'ID': 32, \
                                'Category': 24, \
                                'Title': 192, \
                                'Content':5000 \
                                }, \
                 append=True \
                 )
```

but still it doesn't reduce file size.

Thanks for suggestions to add compression, both the appended and newly dumped files are not compressed per requirement.

Comment: Have you checked compression with `Pytables`? The default is _no compression_: [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#compression)

Answer (score 1):

I used to save .h5 files from pandas DataFrame. Try adding `complib='blosc'` and `complevel=9` to the `to_hdf()` function. This should reduce the file size.