# Trouble with grouby on millions of keys on a chunked file in python pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, bigdata

I have a very big CSV file (tens of Gigas) containing web logs with the following columns: `user_id`, `time_stamp`, `category_clicked`. I have to build a scorer to identify what categories users like and dislike. Note that I have more than 10 millions users.

I first cut it in chunks and store them in a `HDFStore` named `input.h5` then I use `groupby` on `user_id` following [Jeff's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15800314/3478208).

Here is my data: about 200 millions rows, 10 millions unique user_ids.

```
user id | timestamp | category_clicked
20140512081646222000004-927168801|20140722|7
20140512081714121000004-383009763|20140727|4
201405011348508050000041009490586|20140728|1
20140512081646222000004-927168801|20140724|1
20140501135024818000004-1623130763|20140728|3
```

Here is my pandas.show_version():

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.6.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 8
machine: AMD64
processor: AMD64 Family 21 Model 2 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: fr_FR

pandas: 0.13.1
Cython: 0.20.1
numpy: 1.8.1
scipy: 0.13.3
statsmodels: 0.5.0
IPython: 2.0.0
sphinx: 1.2.2
patsy: 0.2.1
scikits.timeseries: None
dateutil: 2.2
pytz: 2013.9
bottleneck: None
tables: 3.1.1
numexpr: 2.3.1
matplotlib: 1.3.1
openpyxl: None
xlrd: 0.9.3
xlwt: 0.7.5
xlsxwriter: None
sqlalchemy: 0.9.4
lxml: None
bs4: None
html5lib: None
bq: None
apiclient: None
```

Here is what I want as an output:

for each user_id, a list `[0.1,0.45,0.89,1.45,5.12,0.,0.,0.45,0.12,2.36,7.8]` representing the score of the user for each category and a a global score. I can't tell you more about the score but it needs both ALL the timestamps and the category_clicked to be calculated. You can't sum up later or things like this.

Here is my code:

```
clean_input_reader = read_csv(work_path + '/input/input.csv', chunksize=500000)
with get_store(work_path+'/input/input.h5') as store:
    for chunk in clean_input_reader:
        store.append('clean_input', chunk,
                     data_columns=['user_id','timestamp','category_clicked'],
                     min_itemsize=15)

    groups = store.select_column('clean_input','user_id').unique()
    for user in groups:
        group_user = store.select('clean_input',where=['user_id==%s' %user])
        <<<<TREATMENT returns a list user_cat_score>>>>
        store.append(user, Series(user_cat_score))
```

My question is the following: It looks to me that the line:
`group_user=store.select('clean_input',where=['user_id==%s' %user])` is too heavy in time complexity since I have really a lot of groups, and I am sure there is a lot of redundant sorting in the routine of `store.select` if I apply it 10 millions times.

To give you an estimation, I take **250 seconds to process 1000 keys** with this technique, instead of only **1 second** in the case of a usual `groupby` with full-in-memory CSV file read with `read_csv` without chunking.

**********UPDATE***********

After applying Jeff's hashing method, I could process 1000 keys in 1 second (same timing as for the full in-memory method), and absolutely reduced the RAM usage. The only time penalty I had not previously is of course the time I take for chunking, saving the 100 hash groups, and getting the real groups from hash ones in the store. But this operation doesn't take more than a few minutes.

Comment: why are u not just reading in all the data and doing a regular groupby? the technique I showed only makes sense with a relatively low group density sand lots of data. you data in memory is prob only a few gigs (the size of the csv is not the size in memory). you should just try this first. if u can't so that then you should simply preprocessing and output the groupby results via chunking and combine after.

Comment: My data doesn't fit in RAM, I already tried. What do you mean by "if u can't so that then you should simply preprocessing and output the groupby results via chunking and combine after" ?

Comment: Please can you give me more detail? I just can't understand what you are thinking to? What I know is that I can't groupby on all my data, and If I groupby chunk by chunk, I dont know how to combine lines with same keys later.

Comment: show an example of what you are want with a small copy-pastable example of input and output. show pd.show_versions() as well

Comment: I am really sorry but I can't paste you the treatment because It's not my property. I can only tell you that I have to groupby following the userIds, then give for each category a particular weight which depends on the clikcs on the category and their timestamp, and that I really need to know all the clicks of a user in a given category to calculate the score. That is why I cant calculate partial scores on chunked groupbys and then sum up. I really need to consider the full information avalaible on a given userId for a given category to proceed the treatment.

Comment: without an example it's impossible to help you. you can certainly dummy up the data and the calc.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I tried to upload my question, I hope It is enough for you. As I say my main concern is to manage to get all the lines of data for a given user_id key without doing a groupby on all the data (my RAM can't allow it), and with not too much redundancy because the calculus has to be made in less than 12 hours. And thank you for your will to help me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I posted an answer for you. I would suggest upgrading to pandas 0.14.1. (0.13.1 should work, but always bug fixes etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a soln for scaling this problem arbitrarily. This is in effect a high-density version of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798209/pandas-group-by-query-on-large-data-in-hdfstore)

Define a function to hash a particular group value to a smaller number of groups. I would design this such that it divides your dataset into in-memory manageable pieces.

```
def sub_group_hash(x):
    # x is a dataframe with the 'user id' field given above
    # return the last 2 characters of the input
    # if these are number like, then you will be sub-grouping into 100 sub-groups
    return x['user id'].str[-2:]
```

Using the data provided above, this creates a grouped frame on the input data like so:

```
In [199]: [ (grp, grouped) for grp, grouped in df.groupby(sub_group_hash) ][0][1]
Out[199]: 
                             user id  timestamp  category
0  20140512081646222000004-927168801   20140722         7
3  20140512081646222000004-927168801   20140724         1
```

with `grp` as the name of the group, and `grouped` as resultant frame

```
# read in the input in a chunked way
clean_input_reader = read_csv('input.csv', chunksize=500000)
with get_store('output.h5') as store:
    for chunk in clean_input_reader:

        # create a grouper for each chunk using the sub_group_hash
        g = chunk.groupby(sub_group_hash)

        # append each of the subgroups to a separate group in the resulting hdf file
        # this will be a loop around the sub_groups (100 max in this case)
        for grp, grouped in g:

            store.append('group_%s' % grp, grouped,
                         data_columns=['user_id','timestamp','category_clicked'],
                         min_itemsize=15)
```

Now you have a hdf file with 100 sub-groups (potentially less if not all groups were represented), each of which contains all of the data necessary for performing your operation.

```
with get_store('output.h5') as store:

    # all of the groups are now the keys of the store
    for grp in store.keys():

        # this is a complete group that will fit in memory
        grouped = store.select(grp)

        # perform the operation on grouped and write the new output
        grouped.groupby(......).apply(your_cool_function)
```

So this will reduce the problem by a factor of 100 in this case. If that is not sufficient, then simply increase the sub_group_hash to make more groups.

You should strive for a smaller number as the HDF5 works better (e.g. don't make 10M sub_groups that defeats the purpose, 100, 1000, even 10k is ok). But I think 100 should prob work for you, unless you have a very wild group density (e.g. you have massive numbers in a single group, while very few in other groups).

Note that this problem then scales easily; you could store the sub_groups in separate files if you want, and/or work on them separately (in parallel) if necessary.

This should make your soln time approx `O(number_of_sub_groups)`.

Comment: Thank you a great deal for your help. Your answer is excellent. Coming from a mathematical background, I really lack these ideas of hashing stuff etc... Feel free to ask me any math question, If I can't answer I will ask friends.

Comment: @user3478208 chunk.groupby(sub_groupby_chunk) is correct (though the other way you specified will also work ); this is a grouper function

Comment: But you have not introduced the variable sub_group_chunk, and If i try chunk.groupby(sub_group_hash) I get an error of the form: long object have no attribute _____get.item____ because It tries to apply the function to the index.

Comment: that was a typo, fixed. you can/should pass a function directly (or more usually an index/level to the grouper), and not directly evaluate it (though practically its the same, but more verbose as you have to pass the object to your function as well). As a followup, can you update your question with the perf of this algo (vs your original method, possibly with a little more color on the data set).

Comment: oh, I meant give some characteristics of the dataset, e.g. 10M rows, how much memory does that take up, something like that. You must be doing some pretty heavy calc; 1000 keys should take way less than 1 sec, but YMMV.

Comment: well I have a formula which takes in consideration the regularity of the user and also penalising certain users for some reasons. In fact I also have to look for the category in a bigdatabase because my data only gives a content-id but I didn't want to mess up my question. But you may be right, maybe I can still accelerate the process.