# Append rows to a pandas DataFrame without making a new copy

Tags: python, pandas

The pandas [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) includes a note:

> Note Unlike list.append method, which appends to the original list and returns nothing, append here does not modify df1 and returns its copy with df2 appended.

How can I append to an existing DataFrame without making a copy? Or in the terms of the note how can I modify df1 in place by appending df2 and return nothing?

Comment: It looks like there is not actually a performance gain by modifying in place: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2801

Comment: This is not currently supported in `pandas`. I'm not sure it's worth the trouble either. Did you have a particular use case in mind?

Comment: heres a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740887/using-pandas-dataframe-with-incoming-real-time-data. What is your end goal here?

Comment: I am reading in a many large data files from an external source and building a DataFrame piece by piece, that I can then write out to a database all at once. The DataFrame will get very large (many GBs) and I want to avoid making a copy each time I add new data.

Answer (score 13):

See [How to add an extra row to a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365513/how-to-add-an-extra-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe/19368360#19368360)

Upcoming pandas 0.13 version will allow to add rows through `loc` on non existing index data.

Description is [here](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) and this new feature is called *Setting With Enlargement*.

Comment: the solution from _Setting With Enlargement_ works only for 1 row. The questions was "appends row**s** ..."

Comment: Also, quoting from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365513/how-to-add-an-extra-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe/19368360#19368360): "However, be aware that under the hood, this creates a copy of the entire DataFrame so it is not an efficient operation."

Comment: Yes, worked with `df.loc[some_index from a loop counter] = a row of a df (= a Series)` or `df.loc[some indices from a range] = df2.values`, see the latter example at [Python pandas insert empty rows after each row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66466675/11154841).