# Reduce memory usage of this Pandas code reading JSON file and pickling

Tags: python, json, pandas, memory, pickle

I can't figure out a way to reduce memory usage for this program further. 
Basically, I'm reading from JSON log files into a pandas dataframe, but:

1. the list `append` function is what is causing the issue. It creates two different objects in memory, causing huge memory usage.
2. `.to_pickle` method of pandas is also a huge memory hog, because the biggest spike in memory is when writing to the pickle.

Here is my most efficient implementation to date:

```
columns = ['eventName', 'sessionId', "eventTime", "items", "currentPage", "browserType"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
l = []

for i, file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.log")):
    print("Going through log file #%s named %s..." % (i+1, file))
    with open(file) as myfile:
        l += [json.loads(line) for line in myfile]
        tempdata = pd.DataFrame(l)
        for column in tempdata.columns:
            if not column in columns:
                try:
                    tempdata.drop(column, axis=1, inplace=True)
                except ValueError:
                    print ("oh no! We've got a problem with %s column! It don't exist!" % (badcolumn))
        l = []
        df = df.append(tempdata, ignore_index = True)
        # very slow version, but is most memory efficient
        # length = len(df)
        # length_temp = len(tempdata)
        # for i in range(1, length_temp):
        #     update_progress((i*100.0)/length_temp)
        #     for column in columns:
        #         df.at[length+i, column] = tempdata.at[i, column]
        tempdata = 0

print ("Data Frame initialized and filled! Now Sorting...")
df.sort(columns=["sessionId", "eventTime"], inplace = True)
print ("Done Sorting... Changing indices...")
df.index = range(1, len(df)+1)
print ("Storing in Pickles...")
df.to_pickle('data.pkl')
```

Is there an easy way to reduce memory? The commented code does the job but takes 100-1000x longer. I'm currently at 45% memory usage at max during the `.to_pickle` part, 30% during the reading of the logs. But the more logs there are, the higher that number goes.

Comment: Searching "inplace panda append", I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196616/append-rows-to-a-pandas-dataframe-without-making-a-new-copy

Comment: I saw that, but my question is multi-pronged; why does the .to_pickle part take up so much memory!? Also, if there is a way to do this without .append, like my second slower but more memory-efficient attempt?

Answer (score 9):

This answer is for general pandas dataFrame memory usage optimization:

1. Pandas loads in **string** columns as **object** type by default. For all the columns which have the type **object**, try to assign the type **category** to these columns by passing a dictionary to parameter **dtypes** of the **read_csv** function. Memory usage decreases dramatically for columns with 50% or less unique values.
2. Pandas reads in numeric columns as **float64** by default. Use **pd.to_numeric** to downcast **float64** type to 32 or 16 if possible. This again saves you memory.
3. Load in csv data **chunk by chunk**. Process it, and move on to the next **chunk**. This can be done by specifying value to the **chunk_size** parameter of **read_csv** method.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to build a `DataFrame` up from pieces, it is generally much more efficient to construct a list of the component frames and combine them all in one step using `concat`.  See the first approach below.

```
# df = 10 rows of dummy data

In [10]: %%time
    ...: dfs = []
    ...: for _ in xrange(1000):
    ...:     dfs.append(df)
    ...: df_concat = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
    ...: 
Wall time: 42 ms

In [11]: %%time
    ...: df_append = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    ...: for _ in xrange(1000):
    ...:     df_append = df_append.append(df, ignore_index=True)
    ...: 
Wall time: 915 ms
```