# Python numpy MemoryError - Loading multiple CSV files into HDF5 store and reading into DataFrame

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas, hdf5

(Using Python 3.3 and Pandas 0.12)

My question consists of two parts.

## First

I'm trying to iteratively read/append multiple csv files - that amount to about 8GB in total - into a HDF5 store based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas) and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997048/how-does-one-append-large-amounts-of-data-to-a-pandas-hdfstore-and-get-a-natural) for creating a unique index. Why I started to do this is because I read that doing so would result in a file that would be fast accessible and relatively small in size, and thus to be able to read into memory. However as it turns out I get a h5 file that is 18GB large. My (Windows) laptop has 8GB of RAM.
My first question is why the resulting h5 is much larger than the sum of the original csv files?
My second question is why do I not indeed get a unique index on the table?

My code is the following:

```
def to_hdf(path):
    """ Function that reads multiple csv files to HDF5 Store """
    # If path exists delete it such that a new instance can be created
    if os.path.exists(path):
        os.remove(path)
    # Creating HDF5 Store
    store = pd.HDFStore(path)

    # Reading csv files from list_files function
    with pd.get_store(path) as store:
        for f in list_files():
            try:
                # Creating reader in chunks -- reduces memory load
                df = pd.read_csv(f, encoding='utf-8', chunksize=50000, index_col=False)
                try:
                    nrows = store.get_storer('ta_store').nrows
                except:
                    nrows = 0
                # Looping over chunks and storing them in store file, node name 'ta_data'
                for chunk in df:
                    # Append chunk to store called 'ta_data'
                    store.append('ta_data', chunk, index=False, min_itemsize={'Placement Ref': 50, 'Click Ref': 50})
            # Print filename if corrupt (i.e. CParserError)
            except (parser.CParserError, ValueError) as detail:
                print(f, detail)

    print("Finished reading to HDF5 store, continuing processing data.")
```

## Second

The second part of my script reads the HDF5 store into a Pandas DataFrame. Why? Because I need to do some data transformations and filtering to get the final data that I would like to have output into a csv file. However, any attempt to reading the HDF5 store I get a `MemoryError`, using the following piece of code:

```
def read_store(filename, node):
    df = pd.read_hdf(filename, node)
    # Some data transformation and filtering code below
```

Another example when this error occurred was when I wanted to print the store to show that the index is not unique using the following function:

```
def print_store(filename, node):
    store = pd.HDFStore(filename)
    print(store.select(node))
```

My question here is first of all how I can overcome this MemoryError issue. I'm guessing I need to reduce the size of the hdf5 file, but I'm quite new to programming/python/pandas so I would be very happy to receive any input.
Secondly, I'm wondering whether reading the store into a Pandas DataFrame is the most efficient way to do my data transformations (creating one new column) and filtering (based on string and datetime values).

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks :)

### Edit

As requested, an censored sample from a csv file (first) and the result from `ptdump -av` (below)

#### csv sample

```
A               B   C               D       E           F           G         H                       I                   J       K               L                               M           N       O
4/28/2013 0:00  1   4/25/2013 20:34 View    Anon 2288 optional1   Optional2   Anon | 306742    252.027.323-306742  8.05    10303:41916417  14613669178715620788:10303      Duplicate   Anon  Display
4/28/2013 0:00  2   4/27/2013 13:40 View    Anon 2289 optional1   Optional2   Anon | 306742    252.027.323-306742  8.05    10303:41916417  14613669178715620788:10303      Duplicate   Anon  Display
4/28/2013 0:00  1   4/27/2013 23:41 View    Anon 5791 optional1   Optional2   Anon | 304142    478.323.464-304142  20.66   10304:37464168  14613663710835083509:10305      Duplicate   Anon  Display
4/28/2013 0:00  1   4/27/2013 16:18 View    Anon 4300 optional1   Optional2   Anon | 304142    196.470.934-304142  3.12    10303:41916420  15013670724970033908:291515610  Normal      Anon  Display
```

#### ptdump -av

```
/ (RootGroup) ''
  /._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 4 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    PYTABLES_FORMAT_VERSION := '2.1',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0']
/ta_data (Group) ''
  /ta_data._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 14 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0',
    data_columns := ['F', 'G'],
    encoding := 'UTF-8',
    index_cols := [(0, 'index')],
    info := {'index': {}},
    levels := 1,
    nan_rep := 'nan',
    non_index_axes := [(1, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'])],
    pandas_type := 'frame_table',
    pandas_version := '0.10.1',
    table_type := 'appendable_frame',
    values_cols := ['values_block_0', 'values_block_1', 'values_block_2', 'F', 'G']]
/ta_data/table (Table(41957511,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": Float64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0.0, pos=1),
  "values_block_1": Int64Col(shape=(1,), dflt=0, pos=2),
  "values_block_2": StringCol(itemsize=30, shape=(11,), dflt=b'', pos=3),
  "F": StringCol(itemsize=50, shape=(), dflt=b'', pos=4),
  "G": StringCol(itemsize=50, shape=(), dflt=b'', pos=5)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (288,)
  /ta_data/table._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 27 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'TABLE',
    G_dtype := 'bytes400',
    G_kind := ['G'],
    FIELD_0_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_0_NAME := 'index',
    FIELD_1_FILL := 0.0,
    FIELD_1_NAME := 'values_block_0',
    FIELD_2_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_2_NAME := 'values_block_1',
    FIELD_3_FILL := b'',
    FIELD_3_NAME := 'values_block_2',
    FIELD_4_FILL := b'',
    FIELD_4_NAME := 'F',
    FIELD_5_FILL := b'',
    FIELD_5_NAME := 'G',
    NROWS := 41957511,
    F_dtype := 'bytes400',
    F_kind := ['F'],
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '2.7',
    index_kind := 'integer',
    values_block_0_dtype := 'float64',
    values_block_0_kind := ['J'],
    values_block_1_dtype := 'int64',
    values_block_1_kind := ['B'],
    values_block_2_dtype := 'bytes240',
    values_block_2_kind := ['E', 'O', 'A', 'H', 'C', 'D', 'L', 'N', 'M', 'K', 'I']]
```

#### Example transformation and filtering

```
df['NewColumn'] = df['I'].str.split('-').str[0]

mask = df.groupby('NewColumn').E.transform(lambda x: x.nunique() == 1).astype('bool')
df = df[mask]
```

Comment: pls post a sample of a csv file, eg df.head(), and df.info(), and show ptdump -av on the resulting .h5 file.

Comment: pls show an example of the transform u want to do

Comment: Hey Jeff, I added your requests for extra data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to parse the dates in the csv, try adding `parse_dates = ['A','C']` when you `read_csv`; if you do `df.get_dtype_count()` these should show up as `datetime64[ns]`, otherwise they are strings, which take a large storage space and are not easy to work with
- the `min_itemsize` argument specifies the *minimum* size of this string column (for 'F','G'); this is only to guarantee that your strings don't exceed this limit; but it makes ALL rows for that column that width. If you can lower this it will cut your storage size
- You are not creating a unique index; there is a line missing from the code above. add `df.index = Series(df.index) + nrows` after reading `read_csv`
- You need to iterate on the hdf in chunks, just as you do the csv files; see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#iterator), and see the docs on compression [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#compression)

Its not clear what your filtering is actually going to do; Can you explain a bit more? You need to thoroughly understand how HDF storage works (e.g. you can append rows, but not columns; likely you need to create a results table where you append transformed/filtered forws). You also need to understand how the indexing works, you need a way to access these rows (which a global unique will do, but depending on the structure of your data might not be necessary)

Comment: Hey Jeff, thanks for your answer. You actually pointed out a couple of issues I did not know how to deal with (e.g. parsing columns A and C as dates, also min_itemsize). I'm trying out your other tips, will let know you more once I figured it out!

Comment: gr8; also would definitily try this with a smaller size to get it figured out

Comment: Hi Jeff, some intermediate feedback. First, if I add `parse_dates = ['A', 'C']` the file read time increases by a factor 12 (~11 seconds -> ~130 seconds), which I personally find an unwelcome change. Indeed it will allow me to handle those columns more easily, but the speed outweighs the ease of use in this case. Do you know why that happens and or whether a solution exists? Secondly, do you know if there is a dynamic way to deal with `min_itemsize`? I have to set it to 50 because there are a couple of rows where the item size is indeed 50 (though this is perhaps 0.01% of all rows).

Comment: pls post the df.info() of your parses frame as well as df.head(), with the complete read_csv you are using

Comment: Something I just realized, is that your suggestion to read the HDF iteratively would work, but I would still end up reading the entire file into memory, just in pieces, because I'm storing it in a DataFrame. I'm wondering my approach is the right one for this problem...

Comment: You don't need to read the entire thing into memory in general. read the hdf via chunks, process each frame with whatever calculation you want, then write the result to a new table, repeat. That way you only have a fixed amount of data in memory at any one time. There are very few calculations that cannot be done this wa.

Comment: Excellent point, did not think about that! There is filter I apply that filters out about 90% of the data. (However the rest of the calculations have to be done over the concatenated DataFrame.) Thanks a lot!

Comment: [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3202?source=cc) is the grandaddy issue to handle this (not really 'implemented' as of yet, but soon)