# Python particles simulator: out-of-core processing

Tags: numpy, pandas, pytables, h5py, blaze

## Problem description

In writing a Monte Carlo particle simulator (brownian motion and photon emission) in python/numpy. I need to save the simulation output (>>10GB) to a file and process the data in a second step. Compatibility with both Windows and Linux is important.

The number of particles (`n_particles`) is 10-100. The number of time-steps (`time_size`) is ~10^9.

The simulation has 3 steps (the code below is for an all-in-RAM version):

1. Simulate (and store) an **`emission`** rate array (contains many almost-0 elements):

   - shape (`n_particles` x `time_size`), float32, size **80GB**
2. Compute **`counts`** array, (random values from a Poisson process with previously computed rates):

   - shape (`n_particles` x `time_size`), uint8, size **20GB**

     ```
     counts = np.random.poisson(lam=emission).astype(np.uint8)
     ```
3. Find timestamps (or index) of counts. Counts are almost always 0, so the timestamp arrays  will fit in RAM.

   ```
   # Loop across the particles
   timestamps = [np.nonzero(c) for c in counts]
   ```

I do step 1 once, then repeat step 2-3 many (~100) times. In the future I may need to pre-process **`emission`** (apply `cumsum` or other functions) before computing **`counts`**.

## Question

I have a working in-memory implementation and I'm trying to understand what is the best approach to implement an out-of-core version that can scale to (much) longer simulations.

#### What I would like it exist

I need to save arrays to a file, and I would like to use a single file for a simulation. I also need a "simple" way to store and recall a dictionary of simulation parameter (scalars).

Ideally I would like a file-backed numpy array that I can preallocate and fill in chunks. Then, I would like the numpy array methods (`max`, `cumsum`, ...) to work transparently, requiring only a `chunksize` keyword to specify how much of the array to load at each iteration.

Even better, I would like a **Numexpr** that operates not between cache and RAM but between RAM and hard drive.

#### What are the practical options

As a first option
I started experimenting with pyTables, but I'm not happy with its complexity and abstractions (so different from numpy). Moreover my current solution (read below) is UGLY and not very efficient.

So my options for which I seek an answer are

1. implement a numpy array with required functionality (how?)
2. use pytable in a smarter way (different data-structures/methods)
3. use another library: h5py, blaze, pandas... (I haven't tried any of them so far).

## Tentative solution (pyTables)

I save the simulation parameters in `'/parameters'` group: each parameter is converted to a numpy array scalar. Verbose solution but it works.

I save `emission` as an Extensible array (`EArray`), because I generate the data in chunks and I need to append each new chunk (I know the final size though). Saving `counts` is more problematic. If a save it like a pytable array it's difficult to perform queries like "counts >= 2". Therefore I saved counts as multiple tables (one per particle) [UGLY] and I query with `.get_where_list('counts >= 2')`. I'm not sure this is space-efficient, and
generating all these tables instead of using a single array, clobbers significantly the HDF5 file. Moreover, strangely enough, creating those tables require creating a custom dtype (even for standard numpy dtypes):

```
    dt = np.dtype([('counts', 'u1')])        
    for ip in xrange(n_particles):
        name = "particle_%d" % ip
        data_file.create_table(
                    group, name, description=dt, chunkshape=chunksize,
                    expectedrows=time_size,
                    title='Binned timetrace of emitted ph (bin = t_step)'
                        ' - particle_%d' % particle)
```

Each particle-counts "table" has a different name (`name = "particle_%d" % ip`) and that I need to put them in a python list for easy iteration.

**EDIT**: The result of this question is a Brownian Motion simulator called [PyBroMo](http://tritemio.github.io/PyBroMo/).

Comment: pandas provides a nice interface to PyTables, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables. You should put separate data in separate HDF5 files, if you are not going to query them together. A table is a nice straightforward structure to do what you are describing, can be appended, and compressed.

Comment: I see. Logically I would store the particle counts in a single table, one column per particle (and 10^9 rows). Then I would query each column for counts > x. Is that inefficient? Why you suggest separate files? Also, is there a space overhead (due to the index) in a 1D table vs 1D array?

Comment: It pretty space efficient. You can use compression. And you can query each column individually. Separate files are useful if the data is 'separate'. e.g. I oftentimes different processes appending data, which you can ONLY do in separate files. (reading is ok on multi-process though). 1 gigarow is big as is 80GB, but say its 20% bigger, does that actually matter? And remember compression can help a lot here. See http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/optimization.html

Comment: just an idea, when you say: "Simulate (and store) an emission rate array (contains many 0 or almost-0 elements) ", is it necessary to store it as float32? if most things are zero or almost zero, aint it better to just store the indices where its not zero, and their values, knowing that the rest is zero? (i guess something sparse-like or so?)  - another question: is num_particles and n_particles the same? i assume the first one is just a typo and should be n_particles everywhere?

Comment: `emission` is result of a function evaluated on the particle trajectories (3D brownian motion). The trajectories are "full arrays", but discarded after emission computation. Emission is small (but not 0) most of the time. This results in `counts` being 0 most of the time. I could in principle store only the `timestamps`, that is the "index" of where `counts > 0`. But `counts` does not fit in ram so the index must be found chunk-by-chunk (which requires some index arithmetics). But yes it's a possible way if turns out that storing `counts` is too expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PyTable Solution

Since functionality provided by Pandas is not needed, and the processing is much slower (see notebook below), the best approach is using PyTables or h5py directly. I've tried only the pytables approach so far.

All tests were performed in this notebook:

- [Python particles simulator: numpy out-of-core processing](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/tritemio/8293590)

### Introduction to pytables data-structures

> Reference: [Official PyTables Docs](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/index.html)

Pytables allows store data in HDF5 files in 2 types of formats: arrays and tables.

#### Arrays

There are 3 types of arrays `Array`, `CArray` and `EArray`. They all allow to store and retrieve (multidimensional) slices with a notation similar to numpy slicing.

```
# Write data to store (broadcasting works)
array1[:]  = 3

# Read data from store
in_ram_array = array1[:]
```

For optimization in some use cases, `CArray` is saved in "chunks", whose size can be chosen with `chunk_shape` at creation time.

`Array` and `CArray` size is fixed at creation time. You can fill/write the array chunk-by-chunk after creation though. Conversely `EArray` can be extended with the `.append()` method.

#### Tables

The `table` is a quite different beast. It's basically a "table". You have only 1D index and each element is a row. Inside each row there are the "columns" data types, each columns can have a different type. It you are familiar with [numpy record-arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), a table is basically an 1D record-array, with each element having many fields as the columns.

1D or 2D numpy arrays can be stored in tables but it's a bit more tricky: we need to create a row data type. For example to store an 1D uint8 numpy array we need to do:

```
table_uint8 = np.dtype([('field1', 'u1')])
table_1d = data_file.create_table('/', 'array_1d', description=table_uint8)
```

So why using tables? Because, differently from arrays, tables can be efficiently queried. For example, if we want to search for elements > 3 in a huge disk-based table we can do:

```
index = table_1d.get_where_list('field1 > 3')
```

Not only it is simple (compared with arrays where we need to scan the whole file in chunks and build `index` in a loop) but it is also very extremely fast.

### How to store simulation parameters

The best way to store simulation parameters is to use a group (i.e. `/parameters`), convert each scalar to numpy array and store it as `CArray`.

### Array for "`emission`"

`emission` is the biggest array that is generated and read sequentially. For this usage pattern A good data structure is `EArray`. On "simulated" data with ~50% of zeros elements **blosc** compression (`level=5`) achieves 2.2x compression ratio. I found that a chunk-size of 2^18 (256k) has the minimum processing time.

### Storing "`counts`"

Storing also "`counts`" will increase the file size by 10% and will take 40% more time to compute timestamps. Having `counts` stored is not an advantage per-se because only the timestamps are needed in the end.

The advantage is that recostructing the index (timestamps) is simpler because we query the full time axis in a single command (`.get_where_list('counts >= 1')`). Conversely, with chunked processing, we need to perform some index arithmetics that is a bit tricky, and maybe a burden to maintain.

However the the code complexity may be small compared to all the other operations (sorting and merging) that are needed in both cases.

### Storing "`timestamps`"

Timestamps can be accumulated in RAM. However, we don't know the arrays size before starting and a final `hstack()` call is needed to "merge" the different chunks stored in a list. This doubles the memory requirements so the RAM may be insufficient.

We can store as-we-go timestamps to a table using `.append()`. At the end we can load the table in memory with `.read()`. This is only 10% slower than all-in-memory computation but avoids the "double-RAM" requirement. Moreover we can avoid the final full-load and have minimal RAM usage.

## H5Py

**H5py** is a much simpler library than **pytables**. For this use-case of (mainly) sequential processing seems a better fit than pytables. The only missing feature is the lack of 'blosc' compression. If this results in a big performance penalty remains to be tested.

Comment: this test is completely misleading. In your code, you have data structure has much longer column than row, which is not optimal for both pytables and pandas. Then you forgot to do fsync after the flush(), which of course ignore the actual disk writing time for pytables. You also forgot the set the expectedrows in HDFStore. Last you forgot to disable the on-fly indexing mechanism during store.append(). If you fix all this problem, pytables and pandas.HDFStore actually give out same performance.

Answer (score 3):

Dask.array can perform chunked operations like `max`, `cumsum`, etc. on an  on-disk array like PyTables or h5py.

```
import h5py
d = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5')['/data']
import dask.array as da
x = da.from_array(d, chunks=(1000, 1000))
```

X looks and feels like a numpy array and copies much of the API.  Operations on x will create a DAG of in-memory operations which will execute efficiently using multiple cores streaming from disk as necessary

```
da.exp(x).mean(axis=0).compute()
```

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/

```
conda install dask
or 
pip install dask
```

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html#hdfstore) for how to store your parameters in the HDF5 file (it pickles, so you can store them how you have them; their is a 64kb limit on the size of the pickle).

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

n_particles = 10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
chunk_size = 1000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

# 1) create a new emission file, compressing as we go                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
emission = pd.HDFStore('emission.hdf',mode='w',complib='blosc')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

# generate simulated data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
for i in range(10):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(np.random.randn(chunk_size,n_particles)),dtype='float32')                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

    # create a globally unique index (time)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997048/how-does-one-append-large-amounts-of-

    data-to-a-pandas-hdfstore-and-get-a-natural/16999397#16999397                                                                                                                                                              
        try:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            nrows = emission.get_storer('df').nrows                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        except:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            nrows = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

        df.index = pd.Series(df.index) + nrows                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        emission.append('df',df)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

    emission.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    # 2) create counts                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    cs = pd.HDFStore('counts.hdf',mode='w',complib='blosc')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

    # this is an iterator, can be any size                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    for df in pd.read_hdf('emission.hdf','df',chunksize=200):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

        counts = pd.DataFrame(np.random.poisson(lam=df).astype(np.uint8))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

        # set the index as the same                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        counts.index = df.index                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

        # store the sum across all particles (as most are zero this will be a 
        # nice sub-selector                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        # better maybe to have multiple of these sums that divide the particle space                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        # you don't have to do this but prob more efficient                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        # you can do this in another file if you want/need                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        counts['particles_0_4'] = counts.iloc[:,0:4].sum(1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        counts['particles_5_9'] = counts.iloc[:,5:9].sum(1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

        # make the non_zero column indexable                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        cs.append('df',counts,data_columns=['particles_0_4','particles_5_9'])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

    cs.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    # 3) find interesting counts                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    print pd.read_hdf('counts.hdf','df',where='particles_0_4>0')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    print pd.read_hdf('counts.hdf','df',where='particles_5_9>0')
```

You can alternatively, make each particle a data_column and select on them individually.

and some output (pretty active emission in this case :)

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  particles_0_4  particles_5_9
0   2  2  2  3  2  1  0  2  1  0              9              4
1   1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  3  0              1              4
2   0  2  0  0  2  0  0  1  2  0              2              3
3   0  0  0  1  1  0  0  2  0  3              1              2
4   3  1  0  2  1  0  0  1  0  0              6              1
5   1  0  0  1  0  0  0  3  0  0              2              3
6   0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0              1              1
7   0  2  0  2  0  0  0  0  2  0              4              2
8   0  0  0  1  3  0  0  0  0  1              1              0
10  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1              1              0
11  0  0  1  1  0  2  0  1  2  1              2              5
12  0  2  2  4  0  0  1  1  0  1              8              2
13  0  2  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0              3              2
14  1  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0              1              3
15  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0              1              0
16  0  0  0  4  3  0  3  0  1  0              4              4
17  0  2  2  3  0  0  2  2  0  2              7              4
18  0  1  2  1  0  0  3  2  1  2              4              6
19  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  2  1  1              2              4
20  0  0  2  1  2  2  1  0  0  1              3              3
22  0  1  2  2  0  0  0  0  1  0              5              1
23  0  2  4  1  0  1  2  0  0  2              7              3
24  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  2  0              3              3
26  1  3  0  4  1  0  0  0  2  1              8              2
27  0  1  1  4  0  1  2  0  0  0              6              3
28  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0              1              0
29  0  2  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0              2              1
30  0  1  0  2  1  2  0  2  1  1              3              5
31  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1              2              3
32  3  0  2  1  0  0  1  0  1  0              6              2
33  1  3  1  0  4  1  1  0  1  4              5              3
34  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  1              2              3
35  0  1  0  0  1  1  2  0  1  0              1              4
36  1  0  1  0  1  2  1  2  0  1              2              5
37  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  3  0              1              3
38  2  5  0  0  0  3  0  1  0  0              7              4
39  1  0  0  2  1  1  3  0  0  1              3              4
40  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  4  2  2              1              6
41  0  3  3  1  1  2  0  0  2  0              7              4
42  0  1  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  1              3              0
43  0  0  2  0  5  0  3  2  1  1              2              6
44  0  2  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0              3              1
45  1  0  0  2  0  0  0  1  4  0              3              5
46  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0              2              2
48  3  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0              3              2
50  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  2  1              2              3
51  0  0  2  0  0  0  2  3  1  1              2              6
52  0  0  2  3  2  3  1  0  1  5              5              5
53  0  0  0  2  1  1  0  0  1  1              2              2
54  0  1  2  2  2  0  1  0  2  0              5              3
55  0  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  3  2              3              3
56  0  1  0  0  0  2  2  0  1  1              1              5
57  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0              1              1
58  6  1  2  0  2  2  0  0  0  0              9              2
59  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  2  0              2              2
60  2  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1              2              1
61  0  0  3  1  1  2  0  0  1  0              4              3
62  2  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  2  1              3              3
63  2  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0              3              1
65  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  5  0  1              1              6
   .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..            ...            ...

[9269 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm testing you approach, and report back soon.

Comment: I can't run the counts generation part of your code, it says: `NotImplementedError: indexing 64-bit unsigned integer columns is not supported yet, sorry`

Comment: You can see the error at the end of this notebook:http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/tritemio/8293590

Comment: you need pytables 3.0.0, pandas 0.12

Comment: That's what I have, from Anaconda

Comment: might be a bug in type conversion in 0.12: try using int8 rather than uint8; could also be an architecture / os issue - you are 64bit? Linux? uint sometimes is odd. shoe counts.dtypes before appending; you don't want uint64

Comment: I confirmed that on 0.13 this upcast works properly but on a 32-bit system it casts to uint64. Just do ``counts.astype(int64).iloc[:,0:4].sum(1)`` to compute the sum and avoid ``uint64`` (or really just use ``int8``). They have the same storage requirement in any event.

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenMM to simulate particles (https://github.com/SimTk/openmm) and MDTraj (https://github.com/rmcgibbo/mdtraj) to handle trajectory IO.

Answer (score 0):

The `pytables vs pandas.HDFStore` tests in the accepted answer is completely misleading:

- The first critical error is the timing did not apply `os.fsync` after
  flush, which make the speed test unstable. So sometime, the pytables
  function is accidentally much faster.
- The 2nd problem is the pytables and pandas versions have completely
  different shapes due to misunderstanding the `pytables.EArray`'s
  shape arg. The author try to append column into pytables version but
  append row into pandas version.
- The 3rd problem is the author used different `chunkshape` during
  comparison.
- The author also forgot to disable the table index generation during `store.append()` which is a time consuming process.

The follow table showed the performance results from his version and my fixes.
`tbold` is his pytables version,  `pdold` is his pandas version. `tbsync` and `pdsync` are his version with `fsync()` after `flush()` and also disable the table index generation during append. the `tbopt` and `pdopt` are my optimized version, with `blosc:lz4` and complevel 9.

```
| name   |   dt |   data size [MB] |   comp ratio % | chunkshape   | shape         | clib            | indexed   |
|:-------|-----:|-----------------:|---------------:|:-------------|:--------------|:----------------|:----------|
| tbold  | 5.11 |           300.00 |          84.63 | (15, 262144) | (15, 5242880) | blosc[5][1]     | False     |
| pdold  | 8.39 |           340.00 |          39.26 | (1927,)      | (5242880,)    | blosc[5][1]     | True      |
| tbsync | 7.47 |           300.00 |          84.63 | (15, 262144) | (15, 5242880) | blosc[5][1]     | False     |
| pdsync | 6.97 |           340.00 |          39.27 | (1927,)      | (5242880,)    | blosc[5][1]     | False     |
| tbopt  | 4.78 |           300.00 |          43.07 | (4369, 15)   | (5242880, 15) | blosc:lz4[9][1] | False     |
| pdopt  | 5.73 |           340.00 |          38.53 | (3855,)      | (5242880,)    | blosc:lz4[9][1] | False     |
```

The `pandas.HDFStore` uses `pytables` under the hood. Thus if we use them correctly, they should have no difference at all.

We can see the pandas version has larger data size. This is because the pandas use pytables.Table instead of EArray. And the pandas.DataFrame always have an index column. The first column of the Table object is this DataFrame index which require some extra space to save. This only affect IO performance a little but provide more features such as out-of-core query. So I still recommend pandas here. @MRocklin also mentioned a nicer out-of-core package dask, if most features you used are just array operations instead of table-like query. But the IO performance won't have distinguishable difference.

```
h5f.root.emission._v_attrs
Out[82]: 
/emission._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 15 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0',
    data_columns := [],
    encoding := 'UTF-8',
    index_cols := [(0, 'index')],
    info := {1: {'names': [None], 'type': 'RangeIndex'}, 'index': {}},
    levels := 1,
    metadata := [],
    nan_rep := 'nan',
    non_index_axes := [(1, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])],
    pandas_type := 'frame_table',
    pandas_version := '0.15.2',
    table_type := 'appendable_frame',
    values_cols := ['values_block_0']]
```

Here is the functions:

```
def generate_emission(shape):
    """Generate fake emission."""
    emission = np.random.randn(*shape).astype('float32') - 1
    emission.clip(0, 1e6, out=emission)
    assert (emission >=0).all()
    return emission



def test_puretb_earray(outpath,
                        n_particles = 15,
                        time_chunk_size = 2**18,
                        n_iter = 20,
                       sync = True,
                       clib = 'blosc',
                       clevel = 5,
                       ):

    time_size = n_iter * time_chunk_size
    data_file = pytb.open_file(outpath, mode="w")
    comp_filter = pytb.Filters(complib=clib, complevel=clevel)
    emission = data_file.create_earray('/', 'emission', atom=pytb.Float32Atom(),
                                       shape=(n_particles, 0),
                                       chunkshape=(n_particles, time_chunk_size),
                                       expectedrows=n_iter * time_chunk_size,
                                       filters=comp_filter)

    # generate simulated emission data
    t0 =time()
    for i in range(n_iter):
        emission_chunk = generate_emission((n_particles, time_chunk_size))
        emission.append(emission_chunk)

    emission.flush()
    if sync:
        os.fsync(data_file.fileno())
    data_file.close()
    t1 = time()
    return t1-t0


def test_puretb_earray2(outpath,
                        n_particles = 15,
                        time_chunk_size = 2**18,
                        n_iter = 20,
                       sync = True,
                       clib = 'blosc',
                       clevel = 5,
                       ):

    time_size = n_iter * time_chunk_size
    data_file = pytb.open_file(outpath, mode="w")
    comp_filter = pytb.Filters(complib=clib, complevel=clevel)
    emission = data_file.create_earray('/', 'emission', atom=pytb.Float32Atom(),
                                       shape=(0, n_particles),
                                       expectedrows=time_size,
                                       filters=comp_filter)

    # generate simulated emission data
    t0 =time()
    for i in range(n_iter):
        emission_chunk = generate_emission((time_chunk_size, n_particles))
        emission.append(emission_chunk)

    emission.flush()

    if sync:
        os.fsync(data_file.fileno())
    data_file.close()
    t1 = time()
    return t1-t0


def test_purepd_df(outpath,
                   n_particles = 15,
                   time_chunk_size = 2**18,
                   n_iter = 20,
                   sync = True,
                   clib='blosc',
                   clevel=5,
                   autocshape=False,
                   oldversion=False,
                   ):
    time_size = n_iter * time_chunk_size
    emission = pd.HDFStore(outpath, mode='w', complib=clib, complevel=clevel)
    # generate simulated data
    t0 =time()
    for i in range(n_iter):

        # Generate fake emission
        emission_chunk = generate_emission((time_chunk_size, n_particles))

        df = pd.DataFrame(emission_chunk, dtype='float32')

        # create a globally unique index (time)
        # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997048/how-does-one-append-large-
        # amounts-of-data-to-a-pandas-hdfstore-and-get-a-natural/16999397#16999397
        try:
            nrows = emission.get_storer('emission').nrows
        except:
            nrows = 0

        df.index = pd.Series(df.index) + nrows

        if autocshape:
            emission.append('emission', df, index=False,
                            expectedrows=time_size
                            )
        else:
            if oldversion:
                emission.append('emission', df)
            else:
                emission.append('emission', df, index=False)

    emission.flush(fsync=sync)
    emission.close()
    t1 = time()
    return t1-t0


def _test_puretb_earray_nosync(outpath):
    return test_puretb_earray(outpath, sync=False)


def _test_purepd_df_nosync(outpath):
    return test_purepd_df(outpath, sync=False,
                          oldversion=True
                          )


def _test_puretb_earray_opt(outpath):
    return test_puretb_earray2(outpath,
                               sync=False,
                               clib='blosc:lz4',
                               clevel=9
                               )


def _test_purepd_df_opt(outpath):
    return test_purepd_df(outpath,
                          sync=False,
                          clib='blosc:lz4',
                          clevel=9,
                          autocshape=True
                          )


testfns = {
    'tbold':_test_puretb_earray_nosync,
    'pdold':_test_purepd_df_nosync,
    'tbsync':test_puretb_earray,
    'pdsync':test_purepd_df,
    'tbopt': _test_puretb_earray_opt,
    'pdopt': _test_purepd_df_opt,
}
```