# Pandas HDFStore - Get Last Record from Multiple Tables

Tags: python, pandas, hdfstore, hdf

I have a large number of data frames exported to a series of HDFStore files through Pandas.  I need to be able to quickly pull in the most recent record, for each of these dataframes on demand.

The setup:

```
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: /data/storage_X100.hdf
/X1                   frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->2652,ncols->1,indexers->[index])
/XX                   frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->2652,ncols->3,indexers->[index])
/Y1                   frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->2652,ncols->2,indexers->[index])
/YY                   frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->2652,ncols->3,indexers->[index])
```

I am storing roughly 100 data frames in each HDF file, and have around 5000 files to run through.  Each of the data frames in the HDFStore are indexed with a DateTimeIndex.

For a single file, I'm currently looping through the `HDFStore.keys()`, and then querying the dataframe with a `tail(1)` like so:

```
store = pandas.HDFStore(filename)
lastrecs = {}
for key in store.keys():
   last = store[key].tail(1)
   lastrecs[key] = last
```

Is there a better way of doing this, perhaps with `HDFStore.select_as_multiple`? Even selecting the last record without pulling the entire data frame for a tail would probably speed things up tremendously. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `start` and/or `stop` to specify a range of rows. You still need to iterate over the keys, but this will just select the last row of a table, so should be very fast.

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5))

In [2]: df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',mode='w',format='table')

In [3]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')

In [4]: store
Out[4]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test.h5
/df            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->5,indexers->[index])

In [5]: nrows = store.get_storer('df').nrows

In [6]: nrows
Out[6]: 10

In [7]: store.select('df',start=nrows-1,stop=nrows)
Out[7]: 
          0        1         2         3         4
9  0.221869 -0.47866  1.456073  0.093266 -0.456778

In [8]: store.close()
```

Here's a question using nrows (for a different purpose) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997048/how-does-one-append-large-amounts-of-data-to-a-pandas-hdfstore-and-get-a-natural)