# How to query MultiIndex index columns values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice, multi-index

Code example:

```
In [171]: A = np.array([1.1, 1.1, 3.3, 3.3, 5.5, 6.6])

In [172]: B = np.array([111, 222, 222, 333, 333, 777])

In [173]: C = randint(10, 99, 6)

In [174]: df = pd.DataFrame(zip(A, B, C), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

In [175]: df.set_index(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)

In [176]: df
Out[176]: 
          C
A   B      
1.1 111  20
    222  31
3.3 222  24
    333  65
5.5 333  22
6.6 777  74
```

Now, I want to retrieve A values:
**Q1**: in range [3.3, 6.6] - expected return value: [3.3, 5.5, 6.6] or [3.3, 3.3, 5.5, 6.6] in case last inclusive, and [3.3, 5.5] or [3.3, 3.3, 5.5] if not.
**Q2**: in range [2.0, 4.0] - expected return value: [3.3] or [3.3, 3.3]

Same for any other *MultiIndex* dimension, for example B values:
**Q3**: in range [111, 500] with repetitions, as number of data rows in range - expected return value: [111, 222, 222, 333, 333]

More formal:

Let us assume T is a table with columns A, B and C. The table includes *n* rows. Table cells are numbers, for example A double, B and C integers. Let's create a *DataFrame* of table T, let us name it DF. Let's set columns A and B indexes of DF (without duplication, i.e. no separate columns A and B as indexes, and separate as data), i.e. A and B in this case *MultiIndex*.

Questions:

1. How to write a query on the index, for example, to query the index A (or B), say in the labels interval [120.0, 540.0]? Labels 120.0 and 540.0 exist. I must clarify that I am interested only in the list of indices as a response to the query!
2. How to the same, but in case of the labels 120.0 and 540.0 do not exist, but there are labels by value lower than 120, higher than 120 and less than 540, or higher than 540?
3. In case the answer for Q1 and Q2 was unique index values, now the same, but with repetitions, as number of data rows in index range.

I know the answers to the above questions in the case of columns which are not indexes, but in the indexes case, after a long research in the web and experimentation with the functionality of *pandas*, I did not succeed. The only method (without additional programming) I see now is to have a duplicate of A and B as data columns in addition to index.

Comment: `df.query` and `pd.eval` seem like good fits for this use case. For information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases, please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

To query the *df* by the *MultiIndex* values, for example where *(A > 1.7) and (B < 666)*:

```
In [536]: result_df = df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values('A') > 1.7) & (df.index.get_level_values('B') < 666)]

In [537]: result_df
Out[537]: 
          C
A   B      
3.3 222  43
    333  59
5.5 333  56
```

Hence, to get for example the *'A'* index values, if still required:

```
In [538]: result_df.index.get_level_values('A')
Out[538]: Index([3.3, 3.3, 5.5], dtype=object)
```

The problem is, that in large data frames the performance of *by index* selection worse by 10% than the sorted regular rows selection. And in repetitive work, looping, the delay accumulated. See example:

```
In [558]: df = store.select(STORE_EXTENT_BURSTS_DF_KEY)

In [559]: len(df)
Out[559]: 12857

In [560]: df.sort(inplace=True)

In [561]: df_without_index = df.reset_index()

In [562]: %timeit df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values('END_TIME') > 358200) & (df.index.get_level_values('START_TIME') < 361680)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 562 µs per loop

In [563]: %timeit df_without_index[(df_without_index.END_TIME > 358200) & (df_without_index.START_TIME < 361680)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 507 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 53):

**For better readability**, we can simply use [the `query()` Method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method), to avoid the lengthy `df.index.get_level_values()` and `reset_index`/`set_index` to and fro.

Here is the target `DataFrame`:

```
In [12]: df                                                                    
Out[12]:                                                                       
          C                                                                    
A   B                                                                          
1.1 111  68                                                                    
    222  40                                                                    
3.3 222  20                                                                    
    333  11                                                                    
5.5 333  80                                                                    
6.6 777  51
```

---

Answer for **Q1** (`A` in range `[3.3, 6.6]`):

```
In [13]: df.query('3.3 <= A <= 6.6') # for closed interval                       
Out[13]:                                                                       
          C                                                                    
A   B                                                                          
3.3 222  20                                                                    
    333  11                                                                    
5.5 333  80                                                                    
6.6 777  51                                                                    

In [14]: df.query('3.3 < A < 6.6') # for open interval                         
Out[14]:                                                                       
          C                                                                    
A   B                                                                          
5.5 333  80
```

and of course one can play around with `<, <=, >, >=` for any kind of inclusion.

---

Similarly, answer for **Q2** (`A` in range `[2.0, 4.0]`):

```
In [15]: df.query('2.0 <= A <= 4.0')                                        
Out[15]:                                                                    
          C                                                                 
A   B                                                                       
3.3 222  20                                                                 
    333  11
```

---

Answer for **Q3** (`B` in range `[111, 500]`):

```
In [16]: df.query('111 <= B <= 500')                                        
Out[16]:                                                                    
          C                                                                 
A   B                                                                       
1.1 111  68                                                                 
    222  40                                                                 
3.3 222  20                                                                 
    333  11                                                                 
5.5 333  80
```

---

And moreover, you can **COMBINE** the query for col `A` and `B` very naturally!

```
In [17]: df.query('0 < A < 4 and 150 < B < 400')                            
Out[17]:                                                                    
          C                                                                 
A   B                                                                       
1.1 222  40                                                                 
3.3 222  20                                                                 
    333  11
```

Comment: I assume that Pandas multiindex is like a composite index in SQL. Therefore if I am only querying with respect to B and not A. Then does Pandas actually make use of the index or is it doing a table/dataframe scan?

Answer (score 11):

With a 'float' like index you always want to use it as a column rather than a direct indexing action. These will all work whether the endpoints exist or not.

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
          C
A   B      
1.1 111  81
    222  45
3.3 222  98
    333  13
5.5 333  89
6.6 777  98

In [12]: x = df.reset_index()
```

Q1

```
In [13]: x.loc[(x.A>=3.3)&(x.A<=6.6)]
Out[13]: 
     A    B   C
2  3.3  222  98
3  3.3  333  13
4  5.5  333  89
5  6.6  777  98
```

Q2

```
In [14]: x.loc[(x.A>=2.0)&(x.A<=4.0)]
Out[14]: 
     A    B   C
2  3.3  222  98
3  3.3  333  13
```

Q3

```
In [15]: x.loc[(x.B>=111.0)&(x.B<=500.0)]
Out[15]: 
     A    B   C
0  1.1  111  81
1  1.1  222  45
2  3.3  222  98
3  3.3  333  13
4  5.5  333  89
```

If you want the indices back, just set them. This is a cheap operation.

```
In [16]: x.loc[(x.B>=111.0)&(x.B<=500.0)].set_index(['A','B'])
Out[16]: 
          C
A   B      
1.1 111  81
    222  45
3.3 222  98
    333  13
5.5 333  89
```

If you REALLY want the actual index values

```
In [5]: x.loc[(x.B>=111.0)&(x.B<=500.0)].set_index(['A','B']).index
Out[5]: 
MultiIndex
[(1.1, 111), (1.1, 222), (3.3, 222), (3.3, 333), (5.5, 333)]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, but in such a case it is better to keep a duplicate initially of the above index columns as regular data columns. But the fact is that in my case, the initial full table is quite large and is stored in HDFStore, I process each time a different data frame received by means of a query. And to add two additional columns to the HDFStore with redundant data - wasting space. Dilemma ...

Comment: actually if its in a store, then I just wouldn't store the index at all; store the columns you want to query as *data_columns* (which implicity index them), see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#query-via-data-columns, indexes (of the dataframe) are already stored as columns in the table, so you can directly query them

Comment: no so good performance. The use case is loop query HDFStore for sum sub-table; in each above iteration processing the sub-table in other loop. If I'll use in internal loop full indexed HDFStore queries instead of DataFrame the processing time will raise in more than 100 times for each sub-loop query (currently checked with IPython %timeit).

Comment: why are you looping? pls show some code (you could do a sep question if you want), or post on mailing list, or here...up2u

Comment: I meant 'some' (not 'sum') subtable.

Comment: np...what I mean is clearly in memory is faster, but you should maybe split your groups (if you data is big); essentially do a sub-selection on a bunch of groups, then do your in-memory calc, that way you don't have the penalty, but are also able to process the real calc in memory (e.g. your group selection should be > 1) (except of course if you had LOTS of rows in a particular group, like 1m+)

Comment: I used some ideas of your [“Large data” work flows using pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas) post answer. The HDFStore: two index columns, TIME and EXTENT, and one data column REQ. I loop over all existent extents with query. In the received DataFrame I loop over TIME to make some calculation on time window size REQ_TW, mean(REQ_TW)+k*std(REQ_TW) and others. Store the calculated data for each EXTENT in different HDF table. After that made some new calculation on the previous results.

Comment: I found a solution - see below.