# Creating pandas dataframe from formatted text stored in clipboard

Tags: python, pandas, fixed

Is there a way to read a fixed widths file from clipboard to a dataframe in pandas/python? I have a datatable I c/p from an application and I am attempting to use an automation tool to load it directly into a jupyter notebook. I only know about pd.read_fwf which requires reading a text file. Is there a work around?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can do that in Linux with Xlib(see [this](https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib/blob/master/examples/get_selection.py)), I would assume you can do it other operating systems too but I've got 0 experience with other OS'es.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.read_clipboard()` already?

Comment: You may also want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45741989/5741205)