# pandas operations on part of multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Any help to solve the following problem would be appreciated.

I have the following df1:

```
                    2020-12-13
user_id currency              
4       1WO       1
        ADH       23
        ALX       5
12223   AMLT      7
        ANCT      9
        ARE       1
```

df2:

```
created_at    2020-12-13
currency                
1WO         1    
ALX         1
```

I do the following code:

```
df1.loc[4] = df1.loc[4].sub(df2, axis=1, level='currency', fill_value=0)
```

output:

```
                    2020-12-13
user_id currency              
4       1WO       nan
        ADH       nan
        ALX       nan
12223   AMLT      7
        ANCT      9
        ARE       1
```

output desired

```
                    2020-12-13
user_id currency              
4       1WO       0
        ADH       23
        ALX       4
12223   AMLT      7
        ANCT      9
        ARE       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double `[]` for `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex`:

```
print (df1.loc[[4]].sub(df2, axis=1, level='currency', fill_value=0))
                  2020-12-13
user_id currency            
4       1WO              0.0
        ADH             23.0
        ALX              4.0


df1.loc[[4]] = df1.loc[[4]].sub(df2, axis=1, level='currency', fill_value=0)
print (df1)
                  2020-12-13
user_id currency            
4       1WO              0.0
        ADH             23.0
        ALX              4.0
12223   AMLT             7.0
        ANCT             9.0
        ARE              1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sub` on the entire `df1` instead of just a slice from the MultiIndex:

```py
df1.sub(df2, level=1, fill_value=0)

                  2020-12-13
user_id currency            
4.0     1WO              0.0
        ADH             23.0
        ALX              4.0
12223.0 AMLT             7.0
        ANCT             9.0
        ARE              1.0
```

Note: I used @MaxU's great [`read_clipboard_mi()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740537/copying-multiindex-dataframes-with-pd-read-clipboard) to import OP's MultiIndex data frames by copy/paste.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i forgot to mention that there could be the same currency in different user_id. So I need to specifiy the user_id.