# Pandas selection by MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Question about selecting rows by MultiIndex.

df:

```
              colA   ColB

   A1   B1   1  ca1  cb1
             2  ca2  cb2
        B2   1  ca3  cb3
             2  ca4  cb4 
   A2   B1   1  ca5  cb5
             2  ca6  cb6
        B2   1  ca7  cb7
             2  ca8  cb8
```

I want to select colA from A2/B1 where MultiIndex levels(2) > 1.
I'm doing it in multiple steps:

```
df1=df.loc[A2,[B7],:,]
```

for some reason I have to present level(1) in brackets

```
df1.index = x1.index.droplevel(0)

df1.index = x1.index.droplevel(0)

df1.loc[1:,'colA']
```

I know it is way too much but I cant figure how to do it simpler. Ways I can think of don't want to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query MultiIndex index columns values in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921010/how-to-query-multiindex-index-columns-values-in-pandas)

Comment: ^ index in the dupe above is a named index, so it doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Ranny, please post some reproducible data next time. You can do it easily with `df.to_dict()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do it in two operations. First use `loc` to select parts in `A2` and `B1`, and then do another query at the remaining index, by setting `query('index > 1')`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColB': {('A1', 'B1', 1): 'cb1',
  ('A1', 'B1', 2): 'cb2',
  ('A1', 'B2', 1): 'cb3',
  ('A1', 'B2', 2): 'cb4',
  ('A2', 'B1', 1): 'cb5',
  ('A2', 'B1', 2): 'cb6',
  ('A2', 'B2', 1): 'cb7',
  ('A2', 'B2', 2): 'cb8'},
 'colA': {('A1', 'B1', 1): 'ca1',
  ('A1', 'B1', 2): 'ca2',
  ('A1', 'B2', 1): 'ca3',
  ('A1', 'B2', 2): 'ca4',
  ('A2', 'B1', 1): 'ca5',
  ('A2', 'B1', 2): 'ca6',
  ('A2', 'B2', 1): 'ca7',
  ('A2', 'B2', 2): 'ca8'}})

# Answer here
df.loc["A2", "B1"].query("index > 1")
Output:
    ColB    colA
 2  cb6     ca6
```

Comment: I like this one (because I understand it better). It works, just I need to sort index before. The only thing I cant pass variable inside quotation marks for querry. How do do this?
a=1;
"index > a"

Comment: @Ranny .`query("index > @a")`

Comment: @Ranny mixing `loc` and `query` isn't as clean as using either though. :-)

Comment: Thanks Tai. Actually I will go with your solution, there is quite big difference in %timeit. 3.6 vs 71.6 (without f assignment). And I'll remember about .to_dict() next time.

Comment: @Ranny Cool. Thanks for letting me know about your experiments.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're working with unnamed index columns, one way is using `query` on `ilevel_*` -

```
df.query("ilevel_0 == 'A2' and ilevel_1 == 'B1' and ilevel_2 > 1")

        colA ColB
A2 B1 2  ca6  cb6
```

---

Another method is using `index.get_level_values` -

```
f = df.index.get_level_values
df.loc[(f(0) == 'A2') & (f(1) == 'B1') & (f(2) > 1)]

        colA ColB
A2 B1 2  ca6  cb6
```

Comment: Before I try. I know that query is little slow. What will change if I add names to index levels?

Comment: @Ranny Not much, actually... just the string expression. If you don't want `query`, `loc` should be pretty fast.

Comment: Renaming `df.index.get_level_values` to `f` is pretty cool! +1

Comment: Thanks for all help. I will go with 'f' method, but will keep other two in arsenal. I just have to get rid of first two levels of MultiIndex. I think reindex will do it just fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ranny You're welcome. Don't forget to vote on our answers, and accept the most helpful one.