# Pandas `DataFrameGroupBy` and `SeriesGroupBy`

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I admit that I am not a Python guru, but still I find dealing with Pandas `DataFrameGroupBy` and `SeriesGroupBy` objects exceptionally counter-intuitive. ( I have an R background.)

I have the dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,9),
                   'code' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                             'two', 'three', 'one', 'two'],
                   'colour': ['black', 'white','white','white',
                           'black', 'black', 'white', 'white'],
                   'irrelevant1': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo','bar','bar',
                                     'foo','bar','bar'],
                   'irrelevant2': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo','bar','bar',
                                     'foo','bar','bar'],
                   'irrelevant3': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo','bar','bar',
                                     'foo','bar','bar'],
                   'amount' : np.random.randn(8)},  columns= ['id','code','colour', 'irrelevant1', 'irrelevant2', 'irrelevant3', 'amount'])
```

I want to be able to get the `id`'s grouped by `code` and `colour`. The code below does the grouping but keeps all columns.

```
gb = df.groupby(['code','colour'])
gb.head(5)
                id   code colour irrelevant1 irrelevant2 irrelevant3    amount
code  colour                                                                  
one   black  0   1    one  black         foo         foo         foo -0.644170
      white  1   2    one  white         foo         foo         foo  0.912372
             6   7    one  white         bar         bar         bar  0.530575
three black  5   6  three  black         foo         foo         foo -0.123806
      white  3   4  three  white         bar         bar         bar -0.387080
two   black  4   5    two  black         bar         bar         bar -0.578107
      white  2   3    two  white         foo         foo         foo  0.768637
             7   8    two  white         bar         bar         bar -0.282577
```

**Questions:**

**1)** In `gb`, how do I only store the `id` column (and not even any index) and get rid of the rest?

**2)** Once I have the desired `DataFrameGroupBy` `gb`, how do I access the `id`s of cases where {code = one and colour=white} ? I tried `gb.get_group('one','white')` and `gb.get_group(['one','white'])` but they do not work.

**3)** How do I access entries where {colour=white}, i.e. lacking the `code` index ?

**4)** Finally, the [manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html) is not very helpful, do you know of any sources where there are examples of how to create and access these grouped objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your problem, you don't even need to perform a `groupby` (but you should read more about it in the [prose docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html).

A better solution would be a `MultiIndex`:

```
In [36]: df = df.set_index(['code', 'colour']).sort_index()

In [37]: df
Out[37]: 
              id irrelevant1 irrelevant2 irrelevant3    amount
code  colour                                                  
one   black    1         foo         foo         foo  0.103045
      white    2         foo         foo         foo  0.751824
      white    7         bar         bar         bar -1.275114
three black    6         foo         foo         foo  0.311305
      white    4         bar         bar         bar -0.416722
two   black    5         bar         bar         bar  1.534859
      white    3         foo         foo         foo -1.068399
      white    8         bar         bar         bar -0.243893

[8 rows x 5 columns]
```

That takes care of *1*.

*2*: Use the familiar slicing syntax:

```
In [38]: df.loc['one', 'white']
Out[38]: 
             id irrelevant1 irrelevant2 irrelevant3    amount
code colour                                                  
one  white    2         foo         foo         foo  0.751824
     white    7         bar         bar         bar -1.275114

[2 rows x 5 columns]
```

*3*: This is a cross-section, use `.xs`:

```
In [39]: df.xs('white', level='colour')
Out[39]: 
       id irrelevant1 irrelevant2 irrelevant3    amount
code                                                   
one     2         foo         foo         foo  0.751824
one     7         bar         bar         bar -1.275114
three   4         bar         bar         bar -0.416722
two     3         foo         foo         foo -1.068399
two     8         bar         bar         bar -0.243893

[5 rows x 5 columns]
```

*4*: Examples are all over the place. Check the pandas / groupby tag here, [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/tutorials.html) section of the docs is being [worked on right now](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5929), the prose docs linked above.

Comment: Thank you Tom, I do not want to store the entire df in memory (it is huge) but just the `id` column. Is this the best way to achieve that: `df = df.set_index(['code', 'colour']).sort_index(); df = df['id']` ? Also, is the reason you recommend this index resetting approach is because it is faster than `groupby()` ?

Comment: For large datasets have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas/14268804#14268804) for an HDF / pandas workflow that is great for doing these cross sections.  I'm not sure about your `id` question, but if you just need `id` there's no need to use `set_index`. This will be faster, but it's also more appropriate. Typically with `groupby`, you're doing a `split-apply-combine` operation. In this case it looks like you just have the `split` part, which the `.loc` and `.xs` indexing handle.

Comment: Great, finally can you briefly clarify this: "I'm not sure about your id question, but if you just need id there's no need to use `set_index`." I only want to see the `id` column, I am not interested in the rest of the columns. What would the code be then?

Comment: If you only want the `id` column, it's just `df = df['id']`, or better yet only read that column in the first place. I'm not entirely sure why you would want just the `id` column though.

Comment: I want to use `df` later in my code (in a separate function) as a lookup table to retrieve the list of `id`s that match a given code/colour combination. Other columns are necessary for other actions but not for this look-up object.