# Manipulating groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have searched through the other questions but none of them addressed this problem. The focus of this issue is to manipulate the groups directly.

Let's assume I have the following data frame:

```
     A  B  C    Bg
0    1  X  1  None
1    2  A  7  None
2    3  X  9     1
3    4  X  1     1
4    5  B  1  None
5    6  X  0  None
6    7  C  8  None
7    8  A  5  None
8    9  X  9     2
9   10  X  4     2
10  11  X  2     2
11  12  A  4  None
```

It is then grouped by 'Bg' column:

```py
groups = df2.groupby('Bg')
for name, group in groups:
    print('name:', name, '\n', group, '\n\n')
```

the groups will be like this:

```
name: 1 
    A  B  C Bg
2  3  X  9  1
3  4  X  1  1 


name: 2 
      A  B  C Bg
8    9  X  9  2
9   10  X  4  2
10  11  X  2  2
```

I wrote the following code to perform some tasks and manipulate the groups:

```py
groups3 = copy.deepcopy(groups)
for name, group in groups3:
    idx_first = group.index[0]
    idx_last = group.index[-1]
    if name == 2:      
        groups3.groups[name] = np.delete(groups3.groups[name], range(0, 1), axis=0)
    else:
        del groups3.groups[name]
print('groups', groups3.groups)

print('-------')
for name, group in groups3:
    print(group)
```

and the output is:

```
groups {2: Int64Index([9, 10], dtype='int64')}
-------
   A  B  C Bg
2  3  X  9  1
3  4  X  1  1
     A  B  C Bg
8    9  X  9  2
9   10  X  4  2
10  11  X  2  2
```

However, I'm expecting this in the output:

```
groups {2: Int64Index([9, 10], dtype='int64')}
-------
     A  B  C Bg
9   10  X  4  2
10  11  X  2  2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas \`DataFrameGroupBy\` and \`SeriesGroupBy\`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21139043/1278112)

Comment: I have searched through the other questions but none of them addressed this problem. The focus of this issue is to manipulate the groups directly.

Answer (score 3):

This is a serious messy rabbit hole...

[image]

**Short Story**
The iteration through a groupby object isn't controlled by iterating through the dictionary returned by `groups`

It starts with [**`def __iter__`**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7aeccd392f0c07ecd1c8d929a0d0312fd8151971/pandas/core/groupby.py#L645)

```
def __iter__(self):
    """
    Groupby iterator

    Returns
    -------
    Generator yielding sequence of (name, subsetted object)
    for each group
    """
    return self.grouper.get_iterator(self.obj, axis=self.axis)
```

Then to [**`def get_iterator`**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7aeccd392f0c07ecd1c8d929a0d0312fd8151971/pandas/core/groupby.py#L1824-L1836)

```
def get_iterator(self, data, axis=0):
    """
    Groupby iterator

    Returns
    -------
    Generator yielding sequence of (name, subsetted object)
    for each group
    """
    splitter = self._get_splitter(data, axis=axis)
    keys = self._get_group_keys()
    for key, (i, group) in zip(keys, splitter):
        yield key, group
```

Which references [**`_get_splitter`**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7aeccd392f0c07ecd1c8d929a0d0312fd8151971/pandas/core/groupby.py#L1838) and [**`_get_group_keys`**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7aeccd392f0c07ecd1c8d929a0d0312fd8151971/pandas/core/groupby.py#L1842)

In both of these, we see `group_info` which returns an obscure and well protected tuple of things that control the iteration.  I couldn't figure out how to completely control the iteration but I could mess it up.

```
a, b, c = groups3.grouper.group_info
a[a==1] = -1

for name, group in groups3:
    print(group)

   A  B  C Bg
2  3  X  9  1
3  4  X  1  1
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, Bg]
Index: []
```

---

My advice... Don't Do This!

**Option 1**
`filter` then  `groupby` again

```
df2.groupby('Bg').filter(lambda x: x.name != '2').groupby('Bg')
```

---

**Option 2**
dictionary comprehension

```
{name: group for name, group in groups3 if name != '2'}
```

Comment: I cannot believe this answer hasn't received any love yet.

Comment: Thx for the support (-:

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So it seems that there is no straight forward solution to manipulate the groups directly.