# python pandas memory errors while working with big CSV files

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having memory problems while using Pandas on some big CSV files (more than 30 million rows). So, I'm wondering what is the best solution for this? I need to merge couple big tables. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the size of the csv file and what is the size of your RAM?. Did you try properties like `low_memory=False` and `chunksize` while reading the data?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to parse large CSV files in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508510/fastest-way-to-parse-large-csv-files-in-pandas).

The inference is, if you are *loading* the csv file data often, then a better way would be to parse it once (with conventional `read_csv`) and store it in [HDF5](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/) format. `Pandas` (with `PyTables` library), provides an efficient way to handle this issue [[docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables)].

Also, the answer to [What is the fastest way to upload a big csv file in notebook to work with python pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010212/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-upload-a-big-csv-file-in-notebook-to-work-with-python?rq=1) shows you the timed execution (timeit) of sample dataset with `csv` *vs* `csv.gz` *vs* `Pickle` *vs* `HDF5` comparison.

Comment: The problem is not in uploading the file. The problem is merging couple big tables.

Comment: Your question is slightly misleading in that case. Although, `HDF5` format still works best for your requirement. Ref [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas) for more clarity.