# Read a large csv as a Pandas DataFrame faster

Tags: python, windows, pandas, dataframe, cudf

I have a csv that I am reading into a Pandas DataFrame but it takes about 35 minutes to read. The csv is approximately 120 GB. I found a module called `cudf` that allows a GPU DataFrame however it is only for `Linux`. Is there something similar for `Windows`?

```
chunk_list = []
combined_array = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in tqdm(pd.read_csv('\\large_array.csv', header = None, 
        low_memory = False, error_bad_lines = False, chunksize = 10000)):
    print(' --- Complete')
    chunk_list.append(chunk)
array = pd.concat(chunk_list)
print(array)
```

Comment: You should consider an alternative serialization format, csv is not really designed for performance. What is the nature of your data?

Comment: as @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned you should save your date in a `.hd5` file. It will be way faster to then load it into a dataframe.

Comment: My data consists of 10's of thousands of 1 line arrays.

Comment: I've been trying to save as `.h5` but the code keeps telling me that there is no module named `tables` even though I pip installed it.

Comment: @RicardoZaragoza what does that mean? 1 line arrays? CSV is *text*, what exactly do you mean by arrays? Also, if you are trying to use hd5, show the code that is failing. Did you try using `pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf`?

Comment: They are just numbers separated by commas. I've been trying to use `array.to_hdf('large_array.h5', key='df', mode='w')`. I have checked the pytables.org prerequisites and installed everything it recommeded.

Comment: I `import tables` at the beginning of my code but i get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tables'`

Comment: This sounds like an entirely different problem, but anyway, likely the speedup from hdf will be significant. However, do you actually need a pandas dataframe? or can you just use a `numpy.ndarray`, because then you could just save it using the native numpy serialization format which would be quite fast as well.

Comment: I figured it out. I `import h5py` and save using `array = h5py.File('large_array.h5', mode='w')`. I'll see if that improves loading time.

Comment: read it via python datatable and convert to pandas frame

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to parse large CSV files in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508510/fastest-way-to-parse-large-csv-files-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at [dask-dataframe](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) if you really want to read it into a `pandas api` like `dataframe`.

For reading `csvs` , this will parallelize your io task across multiple cores plus nodes.  This will probably alleviate memory pressures by scaling across nodes as with `120 GB` csv you will probably be memory  bound too.

Another good alternative might be using [arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have GPU ? if yes, please look at [BlazingSQL](https://blazingsql.com/), the GPU SQL engine in a Python package.

In this article, describe [Querying a Terabyte with BlazingSQL](https://blog.blazingdb.com/querying-a-terabyte-with-blazingsql-4aa6e1a4742b). And BlazingSQL support read from CSV.

After you get GPU dataframe convert to Pandas dataframe with

```
# from cuDF DataFrame to pandas DataFrame
df = gdf.to_pandas()
```