# RAM usage in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So this is my first time working with large-ish data sets (~5gigs) and I was concerned about loading the data into Pandas. I only have ~4 gigs of free ram on my laptop and am concerned that if I read the entire file into pandas, my laptop would crash.

If I load a 5 gig csv file into pandas, will it take up 5 gigs of memory? Will it take more?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html

Comment: The CSV file may be 5 gigs, but once loaded will probably take less than 5 gigs. It also doesn't read all 5 gigs at once, you can set the chunk size. For larger than memory datasets you should be using dask. Your computer wont crash, but the python program will be very slow.

Comment: [Download more ram](https://www.google.com/search?q=download+more+ram&sxsrf=ALiCzsbOGD-WmNUxtkt-QylEXv7nJrkVmw%3A1655302254278&source=hp&ei=buipYufwDc-_tQaBkouIBg&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYqn2fizocqquvb4ShVST5AvC2E5bGjfV&ved=0ahUKEwjn3--20a_4AhXPX80KHQHJAmEQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=download+more+ram&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBAgAEAoyBAgAEAoyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABFAAWABgxwJoAHAAeACAAVaIAVaSAQExmAEAoAECoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)? Joking aside, even if you can load that csv into a dataframe, it would be very limited to what you can do with it..

Comment: Note that if the csv is plaintext, it will be slightly smaller in memory, but if it’s compressed, it will be larger. So watch out for binary or .csv.gz files etc. maybe try opening it in a text editor to see if you can read it. And yeah I’d recommend that section of the pandas docs and dask for sure.

Comment: This question is relevant and has good tips in the answers and comments: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69153017/3888719