# How to read a large file as Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, kaggle, cudf

I want to read a large file (4GB) as a Pandas dataframe. Since using Dask directly still consumes maximum CPU, I read the file as a pandas dataframe, then use `dask_cudf`, and then convert back to a pandas dataframe.

However, my code is still using maximum CPU on Kaggle. GPU accelerator is switched on.

```
import pandas as pd 
from dask import dataframe as dd
from dask_cuda import LocalCUDACluster
from dask.distributed import Client
cluster = LocalCUDACluster()
client = Client(cluster)

df = pd.read_csv("../input/subtype-nt/meth_subtype_normal_tumor.csv", sep="\t", index_col=0)
ddf = dask_cudf.from_cudf(df, npartitions=2)
meth_sub_nt = ddf.infer_objects()
```

Comment: Reading a 4GB CSV file is going to consume a lot of CPU time.  If your goal is to consume less CPU time, can you change to using binary files like Parquet or those produced by `np.save()`?  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

Comment: I want to reduce both CPU and RAM. Will `np.save()` achieve both? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `np.save()` is far more efficient than CSV.

Comment: Your data is large. No way around that. Because of this, you *must* make some trade-offs. There is no library that will allow you to bring 4gb into memory without using at least that much memory. The dask local approach is to split up your *downstream* workflow into chunks which can be processed bit by bit, so you never have the whole thing in memory. You’ll have to restructure your workflow - there’s no point when you’ll be able to magically load all the data. But yes saving your data in a binary format (I’d use parquet) is much more memory and time efficient regardless of your approach.

Comment: Also see this answer for general tips on working with csvs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69153327/3888719

Comment: Your goal is to have the dataframe in memory on the GPU? Do you know about https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/nightly/api_docs/api/cudf.read_csv.html o dask-cudf's version?

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problem. With some research, I came to know about [Vaex](https://vaex.io/docs/index.html).

You can read about its performance [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/process-dataset-with-200-million-rows-using-vaex-ad4839710d3b) and [here](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2021/05/vaex-pandas-1000x-faster.html).

Essentially this is what you can try to do:

1. Read the `csv` file using Vaex and convert it to a `hdf5` file (file format most optimised for Vaex)

   ```py
   vaex_df = vaex.from_csv('../input/subtype-nt/meth_subtype_normal_tumor.csv', convert=True, chunk_size=5_000)
   ```
2. Open the `hdf5` file using Vaex. Vaex will do the **memory-mapping** and thus will not load data into memory.

   ```py
   vaex_df = vaex.open('../input/subtype-nt/meth_subtype_normal_tumor.csv.hdf5')
   ```

Now you can perform operations on your Vaex dataframe just like you would be doing with Pandas. It will be blazingly fast and you will certainly notice huge performance gains (lower CPU and memory usage).

You can also try to read your `csv` file directly into Vaex dataframe without converting it to `hdf5`. I had read somewhere that Vaex works fastest with `hdf5` files therefore I suggested the above approach.

```py
vaex_df = vaex.from_csv('../input/subtype-nt/meth_subtype_normal_tumor.csv.hdf5', chunk_size=5_000)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the code still exceeds RAM allocation.

Comment: At which point does the above solution exceeds RAM? You can control the ram usage of the `vaex.from_csv` via the `chunk_size` parameter. After that, as the solutions quotes, you do memory mapping stuff so you should be fine.. 

I am curious to know since I've done this many times and I've never had any problems..

Answer (score 1):

Right now your code suggests that you first attempt to load data using `pandas` and then convert it to `dask-cuDF` dataframe. That's not optimal (or might not even be feasible). Instead, one can use `dask_cudf.read_csv` function (see [docs](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/nightly/user_guide/10min.html)):

```py
from dask_cudf import read_csv

ddf = read_csv('example_output/foo_dask.csv')
```