# Memory usage is at 29GB when loading a big dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, memory, memory-management

I have 15 csv files, then I load all 15 csv files and concatenate all 15 csv files with below code:

[Jupyter notebook]

```
%%time
df1 = pd.read_csv("test1.csv")
.... for 15 times with above code.

#Combine the code
total_df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10,df11,df12,df13,df14,df15])
```

When I check my memory, its at 29GB used. I am I try to use below code to delete:

```
import gc
del [[df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10,df11,df12,df13,df14,df15]]
gc.collect()
```

But still wont work and still 29GB.

Is there a way to just remove the used memory and leave on the total_df memory as used?
I am planning to perform another processing to total_df but the kernel just went dead when I load such a big dataframe. I hope to reduce the memory and then perform more tasks on the total_df like using PCA to reduce the dimension.

Also, the shape of each dataframe is about (900000,1024). The shape is huge and many rows, so total more than a millions of rows with dimension of above 1k columns.

Comment: this might be helpful too - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69153327/3888719

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try loading the files directly in [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
files = ['test1.csv', 'test 2.csv']

total_df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f) for f in files)
```

Comment: wow can pd.concat consume an iterator like this? I've never seen that. cool :)