# why numpy narray read from file consumes so much memory?

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, numpy

the file contains 2000000 rows:
each row contains 208 columns, separated by comma, like this:

```
0.0863314058048,0.0208767447842,0.03358010485,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.314285714286,0.336293217457,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

The program read this file to a numpy narray, I expected it will consume about `(2000000 * 208 * 8B) = 3.2GB` memory. 
However, when the program read this file, I found the program consumes about 20GB memory.

I am confused about why my program consumes so much memory that do not meet expectation?

Comment: Can you show the exact line of code that reads the data from file? It is hard to answer if we have to guess.

Comment: @BasSwinckels thank you, i use np.loadtxt() to read data. Saullo Castro has pointed the problem and explained this problem roughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Numpy 1.9.0 and the memory inneficiency of `np.loadtxt()` and `np.genfromtxt()` seems to be directly related to the fact they are based on temporary lists to store the data:

- see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L744) for `np.loadtxt()`
- and [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L1610) for `np.genfromtxt()`

By knowing beforehand the `shape` of your array you can think of a file reader that will consume an amount of memory very close to the theoretical amount of memory (3.2 GB for this case), by storing the data using the corresponding `dtype`:

```
def read_large_txt(path, delimiter=None, dtype=None):
    with open(path) as f:
        nrows = sum(1 for line in f)
        f.seek(0)
        ncols = len(f.next().split(delimiter))
        out = np.empty((nrows, ncols), dtype=dtype)
        f.seek(0)
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            out[i] = line.split(delimiter)
    return out
```

Comment: having seen the sample row, there may be a vast memory saving once sparse-matrix would rather be used, doesn't it?

Comment: @user3666197 surely yes, but that would require a more complex reader function....

Comment: sure, the OP issue seems to be the memory-bound, so this was a direction to tradeoff potentially blocking memory-bound issue for CPU-bound efforts, that make both the input per-se & the further processing feasible on even larger dataSETs ( my gut sense tells the OP is not seeking a one-liner or a few SLOC-s, but a feasible approach to input & process similar batches of data with numpy comfort, so will pay the cost of a bit smarter input-pre-processor )

Comment: @user3666197 I've tested here and the problem with `np.loadtxt()` and also `np.genfromtxt()` is not knowing the shape, forced to use temporary lists and `list.append()` (see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L859) and [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L1640))

Comment: That was out of question, Saullo, as addressed in your Answer, the input-processor related issue. Excuse my remark, it just touched the proper ( a more efficient ) matrix-representation for the dataSET.

Comment: @Saullo Castro thanks your explain and your code, i try your code and find it consumes about 3.2GB.

Comment: @user3666197 I want to train a machine learning classifier use the data from this file, so the data in memory can not be compacted. thank you for your careful observation.

Comment: @祝方泽 Thought that you try to import some training dataSET, still, ML tools can work with sparse matrices, without wasting dtype=np.float96 on empty/zero cells. You may benefit on this, once your dataSETs grow a bit bigger

Comment: @user3666197 thank you, your advice indeed give me a new aspect, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `pandas` to handle big data ( text files). pandas is like a excel in python. And it internally use `numpy` to represent the data.

HDF5 files also an another method to save big data into hdf5 binary file.

This question would give some idea about how to handle big files - ["Large data" work flows using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas)

Comment: i have not used pandas, thank you for your advice, i will learn it.