# Incrementally and statistically measuring samples with Python (Numpy, Pandas, etc) and performance

Tags: numpy, pandas

Let's say I take a stream of incoming data (very fast) and I want to view various stats for a window (std deviation,  (say, the last N samples, N being quite large).  What's the most efficient way to do this with Python?

For example,

```
df=ps.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample(200000000))
df2 = df.append([5])
```

Is crashing my REPL environment in visual studio.

Is there a way to append to an array without this happening?  Is there a way to tell which operations on the dataframe are computed incrementally other than by doing timeit on them?

Comment: Generally np and pandas perform well when the array is not growing, by repeatedly appending to it you will periodically force it to allocate a new memory block and copy the values which may explain why it borks when you append just a single element. does this post help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas

Answer (score 0):

I recommend building a circular buffer out of a numpy array.

This will involve keeping track of an index to your last updated point, and incrementing that when you add a new value.

```
import numpy as np

circular_buffer = np.zeros(200000000, dtype=np.float64)
head = 0

# stream input

    circular_buffer[head] = new_value

    if head == len(circular_buffer) - 1:
        head = 0
    else:
        head += 1
```

Then you can compute the statistics normally on circular_buffer.

#### If You Don't Have Enough RAM

Try implementing something similar in [bquery](https://github.com/visualfabriq/bquery) and [bcolz](https://github.com/Blosc/bcolz). These store your data more efficiently than numpy (using compression) and offer similar performance. Bquery now has mean and standard deviation.
*Note: I'm a contributer to bquery*