# Easiest way to read csv files with multiprocessing in Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, multiprocessing

Here is my question.
With bunch of .csv files(or other files). Pandas is an easy way to read them and save into `Dataframe` format. But when the amount of files was huge, I want to read the files with multiprocessing to save some time.

#### My early attempt

I manually divide the files into different path. Using severally:

```py
os.chdir("./task_1")
files = os.listdir('.')
files.sort()
for file in files:
    filename,extname = os.path.splitext(file)
    if extname == '.csv':
        f = pd.read_csv(file)
        df = (f.VALUE.as_matrix()).reshape(75,90)
```

And then combine them.

How to run them with `pool` to achieve my problem?
Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Worth reading if you haven't seen it already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas or https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3been9/pandas_speed_up_read_csv_with_multiprocessing/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using `Pool`:

```
import os
import pandas as pd 
from multiprocessing import Pool

# wrap your csv importer in a function that can be mapped
def read_csv(filename):
    'converts a filename to a pandas dataframe'
    return pd.read_csv(filename)


def main():

    # get a list of file names
    files = os.listdir('.')
    file_list = [filename for filename in files if filename.split('.')[1]=='csv']

    # set up your pool
    with Pool(processes=8) as pool: # or whatever your hardware can support

        # have your pool map the file names to dataframes
        df_list = pool.map(read_csv, file_list)

        # reduce the list of dataframes to a single dataframe
        combined_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what does `df_list ` contains?

Comment: @serafeim  `df_list` is a list of the `pd.DataFrame`s that are produced by the pool of processes.

Comment: Is there any case this code won't work? I tried to read excel files instead and sometimes it gets stuck.

Answer (score 7):

[`dask`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) library is designed to address not only but certainly your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am not getting ***map/map_async*** to work,
but managed to work with ***apply_async***.

Two possible ways (I have no idea which one is better):

- A) Concat at the **end**
- B) Concat **during**

I find **glob** easy to *list* and *fitler* files from a directory

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool

folder = "./task_1/" # note the "/" at the end
file_list = glob(folder+'*.xlsx')

def my_read(filename):
    f = pd.read_csv(filename)
    return (f.VALUE.as_matrix()).reshape(75,90)

#DF_LIST = [] # A) end
DF = pd.DataFrame() # B) during

def DF_LIST_append(result):
    #DF_LIST.append(result) # A) end
    global DF # B) during
    DF = pd.concat([DF,result], ignore_index=True) # B) during

pool = Pool(processes=8)

for file in file_list:
    pool.apply_async(my_read, args = (file,), callback = DF_LIST_append)

pool.close()
pool.join()

#DF = pd.concat(DF_LIST, ignore_index=True) # A) end

print(DF.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't against using another library, you could use [Graphlab](https://dato.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.html)'s sframe. This creates an object similar to data frames which is very fast to read data if performance is a big issue.