# Spark python how group RDD items by using special mark?

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark, filter, rdd

I have a huge file (a.txt) as the following in which there is a special mark in file that divides the data into group

```
a1
a2
$$$$$$$$
a1
c1
b1
c2
$$$$$$$$
d1
d2
$$$$$$$$
...
```

I want to use python code like:

```
line = sc.textFile("a.txt")
line1 = line.filter() or line.filter.map()...
...
```

to divide the group items into several groups like the following:
(a1,a2), (a1, c1, b1,c2), (d1, d2)....but could not figure out how to do it, can somebody help?

Comment: @zero323,  I have searched related topics, could not find the duplicated question. If you found it, please give me the link. Thanks. This one is NOT duplicated!!

Comment: You want to combine records based on a specific delimiter, right? This should be done on read what is explained in the linked question.

Comment: a1, a2, $$$$$$$$ ... are NOT in one line. Linked question is different.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is why you cannot use textFile.

Comment: @zero323, I found the link you mentioned, I will double check it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)
mn = df[0].tolist()
def isplit(iterable,splitters):
    return [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(iterable,lambda x:x in splitters) if not k]
isplit(mn, ('$$$$$$$$',))
Out[84]: [['a1', 'a2'], ['a1', 'c1', 'b1', 'c2'], ['d1', 'd2']]
```

Comment: MaThMaX, thanks for the reply. line is RDD format data, do you have a good answer? actually file a.txt is a very huge file >10G. I want to get a direct answer related to RDD format data and filter, or other function.

Comment: @Olafapple, I think this a already an another question... I have no experience with using the [`Spark`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html). But if you would like to use pandas, you can read [How to work with BigData using Pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas).