# How to read data in chunks in Python dataframe?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, chunks

I want to read the file f in chunks to a dataframe. Here is part of a code that I used.

```
for i in range(0, maxline, chunksize):
df = pandas.read_csv(f,sep=',', nrows=chunksize, skiprows=i)
df.to_sql(member, engine, if_exists='append',index= False, index_label=None, chunksize=chunksize)
```

I get the error:

> pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

The code works only when the chunksize >= maxline (which is total lines in file f). However, in my case, the chunksize<=maxline.

Please advise the fix.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is better to use the parameter `chunksize` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). Also, use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with the parameter `ignore_index`, because of the need to avoid duplicates in `index`:

```
chunksize = 5
TextFileReader = pd.read_csv(f, chunksize=chunksize)

df = pd.concat(TextFileReader, ignore_index=True)
```

See pandas [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk).

Comment: Thanks! Now I get df as TextFileReader. The next step of my code demands df to be a dataframe. How can I convert TextFileReader to dataframe?

Comment: My actual data is about 85GB. Wouldn't concatenation make the datafram big? I want to use chunksize to read and write in chunks. Please advise.

Comment: Yes, it will be very big. Maybe you can check [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas).

Comment: That looks very difficult for a novice like me. "df = pandas.read_csv(f,sep=',', nrows=chunksize, skiprows=i)" actually gives dataframe. Can't this be modified to solve my problem. Updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: I use your solution some time ago and I get same error. Unfortunately I never use `to_sql`, so I cant help you with it.