# Expected Python Pandas performance with GINORMOUS data file

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I want to do some analysis an a pretty dang big file:

```
$ ls -lSh jq1pileup
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 balter SomeGroup 80G Nov 15 12:23 jq1pileup
$ wc jq1pileup
 3099750719 30997507190 85744405658 jq1pileup
```

But, fortunately I'm on a cluster with some pretty beefy machines

```
$ free -mhtal
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached  available
Mem:           94G        71G        22G       1.4G       592M        50G         0B
Low:           94G        71G        22G
High:           0B         0B         0B
-/+ buffers/cache:        20G        73G
Swap:         195G       6.1G       188G
Total:        289G        77G       211G
```

I'm finding that reading in my file is taking an extremely long time (like measured in hours). What is reasonable to expect? Doing something simple like getting the shape or, horrors, a histogram again takes hours.

Is this what I should expect for a task such as this?

EDIT:

The file is a TSV file. (FWIW, an pileup of genomic abundance). Oh, and it is not apparent from WC, but it has 9 columns.

Comment: What kind of file is it (CSV, something else)? How do you read it?

Comment: @MaxU it is a TSV file. (FWIW, an pileup of genomic abundance). Oh, and it is not apparent from WC, but it has 9 columns. Adding to original question.

Comment: can you take a random sample for your analysis or do you absolutely need all of it? take maybe every 100th line into a new file...

Comment: @abalter, can you provide a sample of that file (for example first 3-5 rows) and post your code (how do you read it)?

Comment: @Aaron I'm considering that. Some of the things I want to do are histogram and non-parametric stats like Spearman's correlation. Histogram I could do by serial binning and then combining bins. Non-parametric correlation is not so easy (although I could take random samplings of long, contiguous regions (but not sure how to "average" correlation values). There are such options. But brute force would be the easiest -- send it off to the cluster and check it later when done.

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas? There are some good ideas there.

Comment: Those are great ideas! One that really hit me right in the head is that the numbers are all in the `int16` or at least `int32` range. Reading in with the correct data type should help a lot!

Comment: also I would make a strong argument for writing your analysis to work on a stream of data as the file is read in. even if you have to read it twice, you may find this to be a good approach that uses minimal memory. reading an 80G file off a conventional hard drive will likely take no less than 10-15 min assuming maximal throughput, so don't expect miracles

Comment: @abalter, `Swap:  used: 6.1G` - this doesn't look good. You should try to avoid swapping at all.

Comment: Also, if the data is decently compressible I'd try to store it compressed with something fast like LZO, to minimize the influence of the disk bottleneck.

Comment: Have you considered getting more memory and a faster disk? 256 or even 512 GB of RAM isn't that prohibitive anymore, and a M2 disk should easily get you 80-90 MB/sec in raw read/write speed.

Comment: @thebjorn the node has 289GB of total RAM and, at the moment I checked, 211GB free RAM.

Comment: @Aaron that would be a good approach. The Pearson's correlation is linear, so I wrote a function that calculates it by reading each line one at a time and accumulating moments. For rank-based statistics, it's not so easy. I wrote a function that reads in the file and accumulates ranks into a dictionary, then writes a new file the same size as the original but with ranks substituted for the original data, then performs the Pearson's correlation. It works, but clunky. Also, I could roll my own of all sorts of things, but I'd rather leverage Pandas.

Comment: Retrieving the shape takes hours? I'm pretty sure that shape lookup time should not be affected by the size of the array.