# How to replace a df.loc multiple condition with a categorical type to safe memory in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I want to add a column to a very large pandas dataframe `df1` (>10GB as .csv) that indicates if multiple conditions in other columns are met.

In the moment, I am doing

```
df.loc[(df.col1  == 1) & (df.col2 == 0) & (df.col3 == 1), "col4"] = "start"
```

and

```
df.loc[(df.col1  == 1) & (df2.col2 == 1) & (df.col3 == 0), "col4"] = "stop"
```

However, I am getting a `MemoryError` from the first `df.loc` line. This is most likely due to millions of "start" and "strop" strings in memory.

How to replace the `df.loc` lines with a boolean condition to avoid the `MemoryError`, while having the same visual results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I show how to create a categorical Series with small memory footprint.
However, also keep in mind that it might be easier to [process your DataFrame in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14262433/190597) if your problem allows it.

---

The smallest values (memory-wise) in a NumPy array occupy 1 byte. These arrays have dtype `np.int8` (for 8-bit ints), or `np.bool` or `np.dtype('S1')`.

```
In [121]: np.dtype('int8').itemsize
Out[121]: 1

In [124]: np.dtype('int64').itemsize
Out[124]: 8

In [122]: np.dtype('bool').itemsize
Out[122]: 1

In [123]: np.dtype('S1').itemsize
Out[123]: 1
```

The underlying data in DataFrame columns are stored in NumPy arrays.
So to make a DataFrame as small as possible, use a 1-byte dtype.
This creates a DataFrame column of dtype `int8` filled with zeros:

```
df['col4'] = np.zeros(len(df), dtype='int8')
```

Let `1` represent `"start"` and `2` represent `"stop"`:

```
df.loc[(df.col1  == 1) & (df.col2 == 0) & (df.col3 == 1), "col4"] = 1
df.loc[(df.col1  == 1) & (df.col2 == 1) & (df.col3 == 0), "col4"] = 2
```

Note that besides the memory required for the `col4` column, the above two lines requires additional space to compute 4 boolean Series: one for each of the 3 conditions, and a fourth to combine them. If those lines still raise MemoryErrors, you could try

```
mask = (df.col1  == 1)     # <-- requires space for 1 boolean Series, `mask`
mask &= (df.col2 == 0)     # <-- requires space for 2 boolean Series: mask and a tempory Series
mask &= (df.col3 == 1)     # <-- requires no additional space
df.loc[mask, 'col4'] = 1   # <-- requires no additional space
```

If conserving memory is of prime importance, you should stop here. 
However, if you want the 1's and 2's displayed as `"start"` and `"stop"`, you could change the DataFrame column to `category` dtype:

```
df['col4'] = df['col4'].astype('category')
```

and then change the category labels:

```
df['col4'].cat.categories = ['', 'start', 'stop']
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2017)
nrows, ncols = 20, 3
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(nrows, ncols)), 
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df['col4'] = np.zeros(len(df), dtype='int8')
print(df['col4'].nbytes)
# df.loc[(df.col1  == 1) & (df.col2 == 0) & (df.col3 == 1), "col4"] = 1
# df.loc[(df.col1  == 1) & (df.col2 == 1) & (df.col3 == 0), "col4"] = 2
mask = (df.col1  == 1)
mask &= (df.col2 == 0)
mask &= (df.col3 == 1)
df.loc[mask, 'col4'] = 1
mask = (df.col1  == 1)
mask &= (df.col2 == 1)
mask &= (df.col3 == 0)
df.loc[mask, 'col4'] = 2
df['col4'] = df['col4'].astype('category')
print(df['col4'].nbytes)
df['col4'].cat.categories = ['', 'start', 'stop']
print(df['col4'].nbytes)
print(df)
```

yields

```
20   # the number of bytes required by `col4`
44   # a category column requires a bit more space
44   # the change of labels require a tiny bit more space, but not shown here

    col1  col2  col3   col4
0      1     1     0   stop
1      1     0     0       
2      0     0     1       
3      1     1     1       
4      0     0     0       
5      0     0     1       
6      1     0     0       
7      0     0     0       
8      1     0     1  start
9      1     1     0   stop
10     1     1     1       
11     1     0     1  start
12     0     0     0       
13     0     0     1       
14     0     0     0       
15     1     0     1  start
16     0     1     0       
17     0     1     1       
18     1     0     1  start
19     0     0     1
```

Comment: many thanks! Since I continue with df2.groupby(["col4"]).cumcount()+1, I would like to replace the "" cathegory with NaN. Is that possible?

Comment: As of Pandas version 0.19: "Setting NaNs in `categories` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of pandas". So to future-proof your code, don't set a category label to `NaN`.

Comment: You could instead remove the rows where `col4` is empty before applying groupby: `df.loc[df['col4']!=''].groupby(['col4']).cumcount()`.