# How to use pivot in pandas on chunks of data

Tags: pandas, pivot

I am trying to pivot a data that has 1 billion rows and 3 columns. To do this I am trying to read the file in chunks and apply pivot on each chunk. The following script is only pivoting the last row but not the entire file. Does any one know how to apply this on complete data ?

input data

```
r_id       g_id exp
c1      g1      1
c2      g1      2
c3      g1      3
c1      g2      4
c2      g2      5
c3      g2      6
c1      g3      7
c2      g3      8
c3      g3      9
```

Script - Working

```
import pandas as pd

my_data1 = pd.read_csv("test.input", sep='\t')

my_data2 = pd.DataFrame(my_data1)

my_data3 = my_data2.pivot('r_id', 'g_id', 'exp')

my_data3.to_csv("test.output", sep='\t')
```

Chunk Script - not working

```
import pandas as pd

chunker = pd.read_csv('test.input',sep='\t', chunksize=1)

tot = pd.DataFrame()

for piece in chunker:
        tot = piece.pivot('r_id', 'g_id', 'exp')

tot.to_csv('test.output', sep='\t')
```

Desired output

```
r_id       g1      g2      g3
c1      1       4       7
c2      2       5       8
c3      3       6       9
```

Comment: What is number of unique `g_id` and unique `r_id`?

Comment: updated @jezrael. thanks.

Comment: I want to say it depends of data - so what is `print (df['r_id'].nunique())` and `print (df['g_id'].nunique())` ?

Comment: I added more details. Hope that helps. @jezrael

Comment: Unfortunately not, becasue I understand `pivot`. But I need know more information about your one billion DataFrame. So can you add output of `print (df['r_id'].nunique())`, `print (df['g_id'].nunique())` and `print (len(df[['r_id','g_id']].drop_duplicates().index))` to your question? thank you.

Comment: Sorry, you mean the no.of unique rows ids and column ids? unique.rows.ids=200million, unique.columns.ids=10k.

Comment: OK, thank you. Unfortunately I dont know nice solution for large data.

Comment: no problem. Do you have any suggestion for the above example data? thanks.

Comment: Maybe help check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it myself. Thanks for the comments.

```
>>> chunker = pd.read_csv('test.input', sep='\t', chunksize=3)
>>> tot=pd.DataFrame()
>>> for piece in chunker:
...     tot=tot.add(piece.pivot('r_id', 'g_id', 'exp'), fill_value=0)
```