# How to fix AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'assign' with out updating Pandas?

Tags: pandas, merge, concatenation

I am trying merge multiple files based on a key ('r_id') and rename the column names in the output with the name of the files. I could able to do every thing except renaming the output with  the file names. I have the following error probably caused by the old version of Pandas. Does any one know how to fix this with out updating pandas to new version?

Error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                       
      File "multijoin_2.py", line 19, in <module>                            
        result = merge_files(files).reset_index()                            
      File "multijoin_2.py", line 11, in merge_files                         
        pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', usecols=['r_id', 'exp'])          
      File "/users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2007, in __getattr__
        (type(self).__name__, name))                                                                             
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

Input

$ cat test1

```
r_id       g_id exp
r1      g1      20
r2      g1      30
r3      g1      1
r4      g1      3
```

$ cat test2

```
r_id       gid exp
r1      g2      20
r2      g2      30
r3      g2      1
r4      g2      3
```

$ cat test3

```
r_id       g_id exp
r1      g3      30
r2      g3      40
r3      g3      11
r4      g3      32
```

Desired Ouput

```
  r_id  test3  test2  test1
0        r1        30        20        20
1        r2        40        30        30
2        r3        11         1         1
3        r4        32         3         3
```

Working code (except column naming)

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob(r'/path/test*')

def merge_files(files, **kwargs):
    dfs = []
    for f in files:
        dfs.append(
            pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', usecols=['r_id', 'exp'])
              #.assign(col=0)
              .rename(columns={'col_name':os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]})
              .set_index(['repeat_id'])
        )
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)


result = merge_files(files).reset_index()
print(result)
```

Comment: If omit `#.assign(col=0)` it doesnt work?

Comment: it works but it just doesn't rename the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change `exp` as column name for rename:

```
def merge_files(files, **kwargs):
    dfs = []
    for f in files:
        dfs.append(
            pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', usecols=['r_id', 'exp'], index_col=['r_id'])
              .rename(columns={'exp':os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]})
        )
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

result = merge_files(files).reset_index()
print(result)
  r_id  test1  test2  test3
0   r1     20     20     30
1   r2     30     30     40
2   r3      1      1     11
3   r4      3      3     32
```

Comment: I am afraid, your code is giving the same output as my script in the question. It is not renaming the column names using the file names. @jezrael

Comment: Do you change `col_name` to `exp` ?

Comment: Sure done. One more thing, what if the number of test files are 10k (test1 to test10000) and each file has 200k rows (r1 to r200000)? @jezrael

Comment: Then better is some alternative, e.g. dask. Also you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas).