# Extracting value from JSON column very slow

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've got a CSV with a bunch of data. One of the columns, `ExtraParams` contains a JSON object. I want to extract a value using a specific key, but it's taking quite a while to get through the 60.000something rows in the CSV. Can it be sped up?

```
counter = 0 #just to see where I'm at

order_data['NewColumn'] = '' 

for row in range(len(total_data)):        
s = total_data['ExtraParams'][row]    
try:       
    data = json.loads(s)
    new_data = data['NewColumn']

    counter += 1
    print(counter)

    order_data['NewColumn'][row] = new_data
except:
    print('NewColumn not in row')
```

I use a try-except because a few of the rows have what I assume is messed up JSON, as they crash the program with a "expecting delimiter ','" error.

When I say "slow" I mean ~30mins for 60.000rows.

EDIT: It might be worth nothing each JSON contains about 35 key/value pairs.

Comment: can you share an example of your JSON?

Comment: Neither JSON nor CSV are made for large files. You should consider importing the data into a database and process it from there. It might be a good idea to use a DB server with JSON support.

Comment: @KlausD. That's probably the best idea, yeah. I haven't been able to find anyone efficiently doing what I intend using solely Python/Pandas for a large dataset. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas) post might offer a solution though.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like `pandas` and make use of the `apply` method. For some simple sample data in test.csv

```
Col1,Col2,ExtraParams
1,"a",{"dog":10}
2,"b",{"dog":5}
3,"c",{"dog":6}
```

You could use something like

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import json

In [3]: df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

In [4]: df.ExtraParams.apply(json.loads)
Out[4]: 
0    {'dog': 10}
1    {'dog': 5}
2    {'dog': 6}
Name: ExtraParams, dtype: object
```

If you need to extract a field from the json, assuming the field is present in each row you can write a lambda function like

```
In [5]: df.ExtraParams.apply(lambda x: json.loads(x)['dog'])
Out[5]: 
0    10
1     5
2     6
Name: ExtraParams, dtype: int64
```

Comment: But that loads the entire JSON into a column right? I'm basically just interested in a specific value from the JSON.

Comment: responded inline with an example