# Read Large Data Set to Jupyter Notebook and Manipulate

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, out-of-memory, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to load data from BigQuery to Jupyter Notebook, where I will do some manipulation and plotting. The datasets is 25 millions rows with 10 columns, which definitely exceeds my machine's memory capacity(16 GB).

I have read this post about  [using HDFStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas), but the problem  here is that I still need to read the data to Jupyter Notebook to do the manipulation.

I am using Google Cloud Platform, so setting a huge cluster in Dataproc might be an option, though that could be costly.

Anyone gets similar issue and has a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning products within Google Cloud Platform you can create a Datalab instance to run your notebooks and specify the desired [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) with the `--machine-type` flag ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/reference/command-line/create#--machine-type_machine_type)). You can use a high-memory machine if needed.

Of course, you can also use Dataproc as you already proposed. For easier setup you can use the predefined [initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/datalab) with the following parameter upon cluster creation:

```
--initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/datalab/datalab.sh
```

**Edit**

As you are using a GCE instance, you can also use a script to autoshutdown the VM when you are not using it. You can edit `~/.bash_logout` so that it checks if it's the last session and, if so, stops the VM

```
if [ $(who|wc -l) == 1 ]; 
then 
  gcloud compute instances stop $(hostname) --zone $(curl -H Metadata-Flavor:Google http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone 2>\dev\null | cut -d/ -f4) --quiet
fi
```

Or, if you prefer a `curl` approach:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/$(gcloud config get-value project 2>\dev\null)/zones/$(curl -H Metadata-Flavor:Google http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone 2>\dev\null | cut -d/ -f4)/instances/$(hostname)/stop -d ""
```

Keep in mind that you might need to update Cloud SDK components to get the `gcloud` command to work. Either use:

```
gcloud components update
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install kubectl google-cloud-sdk google-cloud-sdk-datastore-emulator google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-go google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python google-cloud-sdk-cbt google-cloud-sdk-bigtable-emulator google-cloud-sdk-datalab -y
```

You can include one of these and `~/.bash_logout` edits in your startup-script.

Comment: Finally I set up the high-memory machine VM in compute engine(52 GB), and built the jupyter notebook on top of that. Took me around 2 hours. Cost is not cheap, around $200 per month.

Comment: Take into account that you can save costs by stopping the VM when you are not using it (you won't benefit from sustained discount then, though). Datalab has an [auto shutdown feature](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/concepts/auto-shutdown). Also, you can use [preemptibles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible) with a startup script if you recreate the instance each time.

Comment: Just added a way to configure auto shutdown for GCE instances, too. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I will try this out and let you know whether that works.