# How to load large data into pandas efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a very wide dataset (1005 rows * 590,718 columns, 1.2G). Loading such a large dataset into a pandas dataframe result in code failure entirely due to insufficient memory.

I am aware that Spark is probably a good alternative to Pandas for dealing with large datasets, but is there any amenable solution in Pandas to reduce memory usage while loading large data?

Comment: seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas ?

Comment: If possible, convert csv into parquet format and use pyarrow or fast parquet packages in spark for faster processing.

Comment: Thank you. its very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
pandas.read_csv(filename, chunksize = chunksize)
```

Comment: Do I need to append chunks later on? My dataset is too wide. Is there similar functionality for columns or should I transpose my df?

Comment: you can follow it up with concat function as such : `chunk_df = pd.read_csv(filename, iterator=True, chunksize=chunksize)` 
`df = pd.concat(chunk_df, ignore_index=True)`