# How to read bigdataset to Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, azure-machine-learning-service

I have several files (11) already as datasets (mltable) in Azure ML Studio. Loading to df's works to all the cases except one. I believe the reason for that is the size - 1.95 GB. I wonder how can I load this dataset to dataframe? So far I did not manage to load it at all.

Any tips how to do it effectively? I tried to figure out a way to do it in parallel with the modin but failed. Below you will find the load script.

```
subscription_id = 'xyz'
resource_group = 'rg-personal'
workspace_name = 'test'

workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='buses')
dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load large data into pandas efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989597/how-to-load-large-data-into-pandas-efficiently)

Comment: Hi! It did not help but inspired me to load it differently. I already posted the solution. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data using an AzureML long-form datastore URI directly into Pandas.

Ensure you have the `azureml-fsspec` Python library installed:

```bash
pip install azureml-fsspec
```

Next, just load the data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("azureml://subscriptions/<subid>/resourcegroups/<rgname>/workspaces/<workspace_name>/datastores/<datastore_name>/paths/<folder>/<filename>.csv")
df.head()
```

As this uses the AzureML datastore, it will automatically handle authentication for you without exposing SAS keys in the URI. Authentication can be either *identity-based* (i.e. passthrough your AAD to storage) or *credential-based*.

AzureML Datastore URIs are a known implementation of [Filesystem spec (fsspec)](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/latest/index.html#): A unified pythonic interface to local, remote and embedded file systems and bytes storage.

This implementation leverages the AzureML data runtime: a fast and efficient engine to materialize the data into a Pandas or Spark dataframe. The engine is written in Rust, which is known for high speed and high memory efficiency for data processing tasks.

Comment: Sounds like a great feature! Do you know if it works if the workspace is on a private endpoint / VNet? I tried this and got the error below (timeout). Thanks!

`Unexpected failure while resolving environment for Datastore 'xx' in subscription: 'yy', resource group: 'aa', workspace: 'bb'.`
 `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='westeurope.api.azureml.ms', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /discovery (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa01b95c1c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))`

Comment: Yes -- it will work behind private endpoint. Is where you are accessing the data also in the same VNET - for example, are you using a compute instance

Comment: @SamKemp I get: Exception: [PyDatastoreSource::list_directory] fails with error: PermissionDenied(Some(AuthenticationError("UnboundLocalError: local variable 'authority' referenced before assignment"))). Do you know how I can solve this? Thank you. (my datastore URI is good but it seems I have some permissions issues)

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, easier than what was posted by the @DeepDave

Instead of loading data from assets, I loaded them directly from blob with the URL, using the modin library instead of Pandas. Worked like a charm

Code below:

```
import modin.pandas as pd

url ='URLLINKHERE'
df_bus = pd.read_csv(url, encoding='utf16')
df_bus.head()
```

To supplement where to find URL.

1. Go go storage and find the file.
2. Right click on the file.
3. Generate SAS.
4. BLOB SAS URL -> that was the link I used.

Hope this help others.