# How to read through large csv or database and join columns when memory is an issue?

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a large dataset that I pulled from Data.Medicare.gov (https://data.medicare.gov/Physician-Compare/Physician-Compare-National-Downloadable-File/mj5m-pzi6)

It's a cvs of all physicians (2.4 million rows by 41 columns, 750MB), lets call this `physician_df`, however, I cannot load into memory on my computer (memory error).

I have another df loaded in memory (summary_df) and I want to join columns (NPI, Last Name, First Name) from physician_df.

Is there any way to do this without having to load the data to memory? I first attempted by using their API but I get capped out (I have about 500k rows in my final df and this will always be changing). Would storing the physician_df into a SQL database make this easier?

Here are snippets of each df (fyi, the summary_df is all fake information).

summary_df

```
DOS        Readmit    SurgeonNPI   
1-1-2018   1          1184809691   
2-2-2018   0          1184809691   
2-5-2017   1          1093707960
```

physician_df

```
NPI          PAC ID      Professional Enrollment   LastName FirstName
1184809691   2668563156  I20120119000086           GOLDMAN  SALUJA
1184809691   4688750714  I20080416000055           NOLTE    KIMBERLY
1093707960   7618879354  I20040127000771           KHANDUJA KARAMJIT
```

Final df:

```
DOS        Readmit    SurgeonNPI  LastName FirstName
1-1-2018   1          1184809691  GOLDMAN  SALUJA
2-2-2018   0          1184809691  GOLDMAN  SALUJA
2-5-2017   1          1093707960  KHANDUJA KARAMJIT
```

If I could load the physician_df then I would use the below code..

```
pandas.merge(summary_df, physician_df, how='left', left_on=['SurgeonNPI'], right_on=['NPI'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your desired output, you only need 3 columns from `physician_df`. It is more likely 2.4mio rows of 3 columns *can* fit in memory versus 5 (or, of course, all 41 columns).

So I would first try extracting what you need from a 3-column dataset, convert to a dictionary, then use it to map required columns.

Note, to produce your desired output, it is necessary to drop duplicates (keeping first) from `physicians_df`, so I have included this logic.

```
from operator import itemgetter as iget

d = pd.read_csv('physicians.csv', columns=['NPI', 'LastName', 'FirstName'])\
      .drop_duplicates('NPI')\
      .set_index('NPI')[['LastName', 'FirstName']]\
      .to_dict(orient='index')

# {1093707960: {'FirstName': 'KARAMJIT', 'LastName': 'KHANDUJA'},
#  1184809691: {'FirstName': 'SALUJA', 'LastName': 'GOLDMAN'}}

df_summary['LastName'] = df_summary['SurgeonNPI'].map(d).map(iget('LastName'))
df_summary['FirstName'] = df_summary['SurgeonNPI'].map(d).map(iget('FirstName'))

#         DOS  Readmit  SurgeonNPI  LastName FirstName
# 0  1-1-2018        1  1184809691   GOLDMAN    SALUJA
# 1  2-2-2018        0  1184809691   GOLDMAN    SALUJA
# 2  2-5-2017        1  1093707960  KHANDUJA  KARAMJIT
```

If your *final* dataframe is too large to store in memory, then I would consider these options:

- Chunking: [split your dataframe into small chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas) and output as you go along.
- PyTables: based on numpy + HDF5.
- dask.dataframe: based on pandas and uses out-of-core processing.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to import the data into a database and do the joins there (e.g. Postgres if you want a relational DB – there are pretty nice ORMs for it, like [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/)). Maybe you can then use SQL operations to get a subset of the data you are most interested in, export it and can process it using Pandas. Also, take a look at [Ibis](http://docs.ibis-project.org/) for working with databases directly – another project Wes McKinney, the author of Pandas worked on.

It would be great to use Pandas with an on-disk storage system, but as far as I know that's not an entirely solved problem yet. There's PyTables (a bit more on using PyTables with Pandas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas)), but it [doesn't support joins](https://www.pytables.org/cookbook/hints_for_sql_users.html#a-note-on-table-joins) in the same SQL-like way that Pandas does.

Answer (score -1):

Sampling!

```
import pandas as pd
import random

n = int(2.4E7)
n_sample = 2.4E5
filename = "https://data.medicare.gov/Physician-Compare/Physician-Compare-National-Downloadable-File/mj5m-pzi6"
skip = sorted(random.sample(xrange(n),n-s))
physician_df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=skip)
```

Then this should work fine

```
summary_sample_df = summary_df[summary_df.SurgeonNPI.isin(physician_df.NPI)]
merge_sample_df = pd.merge(summary_sample_df, physician_df, how='left', left_on=['SurgeonNPI'], right_on=['NPI'])
```

Pickle your `merge_sample_df`. Sample again. Wash, rinse, repeat to desired confidence.