# Memory error while reading large file

Tags: python, out-of-memory, large-data

I am trying to read a 59 GB file and break it to a number of new files according to some id found in the begging of each line. I am running the code below which breaks with a memory error after producing 45GB files. The system memory remains in very low level during all time and suddenly creates a after the code runs for about 2 hours. I have 16GB ram. Am I using buffering wrongly? Any idea?

```
outputFile = '/home/.../folder1'
directory = '/home/.../folder2/'

with open(directory + 'aldk_tab_1mn.csv', 'r', buffering=50000000) as fin: 
    firstLine = fin.readline()
    print(firstLine)

    for line in fin:
        testChar = line[0:4]
        if testChar[0] == 'A' :
            if not os.path.exists(outputFile + '/A/' + testChar+'.csv'):   # first time open a file             
                with open(outputFile + '/A/' + testChar+'.csv', 'a') as foutA:
                    print('file', testChar, 'created')                    
                    foutA.write(firstLine)
                    foutA.write(line)          
            else: 
                with open(outputFile + '/A/' + testChar+'.csv', 'a') as foutA:
                    foutA.write(line)          
        else:
            if not os.path.exists(outputFile + '/B/' + testChar+'.csv'):   # first time open a file             
                with open(outputFile + '/B/' + testChar+'.csv', 'a') as foutB:
                    print('file', testChar, 'created')
                    foutB.write(firstLine)
                    foutB.write(line) 
            else: 
                with open(outputFile + '/B/' + testChar+'.csv', 'a') as foutB:
                    foutB.write(line)
```

The produced error is

```
MemoryError                               
Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-17-761f2fcce982> in <module>()
  6 
----> 7     for line in fin:
  8         testChar = line[0:4]
  9         if testChar[0] == 'A' :

MemoryError:
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268804/4737952

Comment: Could your issue lie in a surprisingly long line in the large file you read? In that case, it might be a good idea to not iterate over complete lines at once.

Comment: have you tried to remove the buffering? BTW can you fix the spelling errors in your question? it's very difficult to read it.

Comment: @Martijn good point. If suddenly a line is 50GB long because it's missing line terminators, then OP's toast. That must be the issue... in that case, reading char by char is the solution, but OP input is probably corrupt instead...

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. No there is no such chance since these are data  measurements of specific variables. I will still check it though since that would create an issue with my data collection process.

Comment: I haven't removed buffering yet since I thought the whole idea for using it is to avoid loading the whole file. I will try it to see if anything will change.

Comment: You may try to lower the buffer down. 50MB seems pretty high to me. Speaking of buffers, you may want to have write buffers as well. So that you don't open write + close write every single time you want to write down a line.

Comment: ok, im not sure what a write buffer is, I should check that. Regarding the buffering size, why is 50MB high? can someone elaborate on buffering usage or share a link?

Comment: If your lines are significantly smaller than 50MB, it might be a good idea to use the default line buffering, at least for the debugging stage. This will already lower the memory requirements by a lot. You won't need to hold 50 MB at once in memory after all.

Comment: You might also want to look into the output of [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory_profiler/) for your code if the problem is not in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, it appears that the file had empty characters after a certain point making the line variable to explode as @Martijn suggested!

So I did slice my file! Thanks guys!