# Alternative for drop_duplicates python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, unique

I am working on some huge volume of data, rows around 50 millions.
I want to find unique columns values from multiple columns. I use below script.

```
dataAll[['Frequency', 'Period', 'Date']].drop_duplicates()
```

But this is taking long time, more than 40minutes.

I found some alternative:

```
pd.unique(dataAll[['Frequency', 'Period', 'Date']].values.ravel('K'))
```

[image]

but above script will give array, but I need in dataframe like first script will give as below

[image]

Comment: You could maintain a Python [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) of tuples of the labels `Frequency`, `Period`, and `Date`, iterating over the rows and checking/updating the set's membership. This should be roughly linear in the number of rows, except perhaps for the tuple creation. I'd be surprised, however, if pandas did not take a similar approach to their `drop_duplicates`.

Answer (score 1):

Generaly your new code is imposible convert to `DataFrame`, because:

```
pd.unique(dataAll[['Frequency', 'Period', 'Date']].values.ravel('K'))
```

create one big `1d numpy array`, so after remove duplicates is impossible recreate rows.

E.g. if there are 2 unique values `3` and `1` is impossible find which datetimes are for `3` and for `1`.

---

But if there is only one unique value for `Frequency` and for each `Period` is possible find `Date` like in sample, solution is possible.

EDIT:

One possible alternative is use [`dask.dataframe.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.drop_duplicates).

Comment: thanks... Is there any alternatives? I need to improve performance of script

Comment: Frequency contains 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 for different dates.

Comment: Could you please give solution for 'Period', 'Date'  - only 2 columns

Comment: @faithon.gvr.py - 50millions is really huge Dataframe. I suggest working in server with a lot of RAM, also some another library like `dask` should be helpful. Also some idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14262433/2901002) should help.