# Reshaping into binary variables using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am still new to Python pandas' pivot_table and im trying to reshape the data to have a binary indicator if a value is in a certain observation. I have follow some previous codes and got some encouraging results, however instead of 1 and zeros as Is my ideal result I get a sum. Please see a small sample data set below

```
    ID          SKILL     NUM
    1             A        1
    1             A        1
    1             B        1
    2             C        1
    3             C        1
    3             C        1
    3             E        1
```

The results I am aiming for is:

```
    ID    A         B        C    E
    1     1         1        0    0
    2     0         0        1    0
    3     0         0        0    1
```

My code atm get the following result:

```
    ID    A         B        C    E
    1     2         1        0    0
    2     0         0        2    0
    3     0         0        0    1
```

Should I remove the duplicates first??

The code I'm using atm is below;

```
  df_pivot =  df2.pivot_table(index='Job_posting_ID', columns='SKILL', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for indicator columns and then get `max` values per index:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('ID')['SKILL']).max(level=0)
```

For better performance remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['ID','SKILL']).set_index(['ID','SKILL'])['NUM'].unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), but then is necessary replace `NaN`s to `0`:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['ID','SKILL']).pivot('ID','SKILL','NUM').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

If want use your solution, just remove duplicates, but better is `unstack`, beacuse data are never aggregated, because not duplicated pairs `ID` with `SKILL`:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(['ID','SKILL'])
df_pivot = (df2.pivot_table(index='ID', 
                            columns='SKILL', 
                            values='NUM',
                            aggfunc=len, 
                            fill_value=0))
print (df_pivot)
SKILL  A  B  C  E
ID               
1      1  1  0  0
2      0  0  1  0
3      0  0  1  1
```

Comment: The unstack is really fast tks.. How do I keep the ID as a variable not as a index on this case ?

Comment: @Ian_De_Oliveira - Last need `df.drop_duplicates(['ID','SKILL']).set_index(['ID','SKILL'])['NUM'].unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: Tks a lot , the unstack function worked really well.. Know I need to learn how to work with big data because my computer did not like the idea to flip 55000 columns , 2500 did ok but 55000 atm only SAS is been able to.

Comment: @Ian_De_Oliveira - It depends of RAM in your PC, but for working best with large data in pandas check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14262433/2901002)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='SKILL', values='NUM', aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()), fill_value=0)
```

Or this:

```
df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='SKILL',aggfunc=lambda x: int(x.any()), fill_value=0)
```

Whichever suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggfunc='any'` and convert to `int` as a separate step. This avoids having to use a `lambda` / custom function, and may be more efficient.

```
df_pivot =  df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='SKILL',
                           aggfunc='any', fill_value=0).astype(int)

print(df_pivot)

      NUM         
SKILL   A  B  C  E
ID                
1       1  1  0  0
2       0  0  1  0
3       0  0  1  1
```

The same would work with `aggfunc=len` + conversion to `int`, except this is likely to be more expensive.

Comment: It worked, tks. R would not flip my table because is too big.