# remove duplicates on large csv file, only look at a subset of columns

Tags: python, duplicates, large-data

I need to remove duplicates for a large .csv file (50+GB), and I would like to do this using python. Several other questions address the issue broadly (ex: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407474/removing-duplicates-on-very-large-datasets) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741564/removing-duplicate-rows-from-a-csv-file-using-a-python-script)), but they deal with exact duplicates.

In my case, the duplicates are not exact duplicates. The setup of my file is such that I compiled this file by pulling rows from several sources, and one column indicates the source of origin. This means that I would like to remove duplicates for a subset of columns. The size of the file means that I cannot load it into memory, so pandas is out.

How can I approach this problem (possibly modifying the solutions I linked to)?

Answer (score 1):

For large dataframes, you can use `dask`. It's syntax is similar to pandas so if you are familiar with it, you will have no problem. Example:

```
import dask.dataframe as dsk
df = dsk.read_csv('my_csv.csv')
```

The syntax for drop duplicates [Here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, split_every=None, split_out=1, ignore_index=False, **kwargs)
```

allows for subsets.

Example:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as dsk
client = Client(memory_limit='32GB') # set your limit here
df = dsk.read_csv("my_csv", sample=100)
results = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['my_col'], split_out=df.npartitions)
results.to_csv(outdir, index=False)
```

Comment: Can you expand on this to show how/when to call the .compute() method and how to save the output as a .csv? I'm having trouble seeing how to do this without pulling the df into memory, and my current attempt to avoid this is not working properly.

Comment: @amquack added an example

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `duckdb`. Here is a quick intro/benchmarking: https://duckdb.org/2021/05/14/sql-on-pandas.html