# Shortcut use panda's duplicated() with a thick csv

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, large-data, read.csv

I can't read a whole 5 GB CSV file in one go, but using Pandas'  `read_csv()` with `chuncksize` set seems to be a fast and easy way:

```py
import pandas as panda

def run_pand(csv_db):

    reader = panda.read_csv(csv_db, chunksize=5000)
    dup=reader.duplicated(subset=["Region","Country","Ship Date"])
    #and after i will write duplicates in new csv
```

As I understand it, reading in chunks will not let me find a duplicate if they are in different pieces, **or will it still?**

Is there a way to search for matches using a Pandas method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates on very large datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407474/removing-duplicates-on-very-large-datasets)

Comment: Nope, In those answers, duplicates were searched  by turning the whole string into a hash and checked among themselves. 
But I need to check the 5,6,10,11,12 column.

Comment: But can't you adapt that to your situation: Build a string out of the relevant columns and work with that?