# Problem with setting dtypes while reading large csv file

Tags: python

I have large csv file ~14gb (124 columns) and i occur memory error while reading `df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\AdamPer\Desktop\Python\Magisterka\test2.csv', encoding= "utf_8_sig")`
I tried set option `low_memory = False` and `error_bad_lines = False`but it doesnt help, so i decided to set dtype and have problem with that.
What i've done.

I made a smaller csv file ~16mb and read it to dataframe and check types of column `df.info(max_cols=200)`

```
Soft              39347 non-null object
Hand_ID           39347 non-null int64
Table_Name        39345 non-null object
SmallBlind        39347 non-null float64
BigBlind          39347 non-null float64
Currency          39347 non-null object
Day               39347 non-null object
Hour              39347 non-null object
Seat_1            39347 non-null object
Seat_2            39347 non-null object
Seat_3            39347 non-null object
Seat_4            39347 non-null object
Seat_5            39347 non-null object
Seat_6            39347 non-null object
Stack_1           39347 non-null float64
Stack_2           39347 non-null float64
Stack_3           39347 non-null float64
Stack_4           39347 non-null float64
Stack_5           39347 non-null float64
Stack_6           39347 non-null float64
Raise_Pre_S1      39347 non-null object
Raise_Pre_S2      39347 non-null object
Raise_Pre_S3      39347 non-null object
Raise_Pre_S4      39347 non-null object
Raise_Pre_S5      39347 non-null object
Raise_Pre_S6      39347 non-null object
Call_Pre_S1       39347 non-null object
Call_Pre_S2       39347 non-null object
Call_Pre_S3       39347 non-null object
Call_Pre_S4       39347 non-null object
Call_Pre_S5       39347 non-null object
Call_Pre_S6       39347 non-null object
Flop_Bet_S1       39347 non-null float64
Flop_Bet_S2       39347 non-null float64
Flop_Bet_S3       39347 non-null float64
Flop_Bet_S4       39347 non-null float64
Flop_Bet_S5       39347 non-null float64
Flop_Bet_S6       39347 non-null float64
Flop_Raise_S1     39347 non-null object
Flop_Raise_S2     39347 non-null object
Flop_Raise_S3     39347 non-null object
Flop_Raise_S4     39347 non-null object
Flop_Raise_S5     39347 non-null object
Flop_Raise_S6     39347 non-null object
Flop_Call_S1      39347 non-null object
Flop_Call_S2      39347 non-null object
Flop_Call_S3      39347 non-null object
Flop_Call_S4      39347 non-null object
Flop_Call_S5      39347 non-null object
Flop_Call_S6      39347 non-null object
Saw_Flop_S1       39347 non-null int64
Saw_Flop_S2       39347 non-null int64
Saw_Flop_S3       39347 non-null int64
Saw_Flop_S4       39347 non-null int64
Saw_Flop_S5       39347 non-null int64
Saw_Flop_S6       39347 non-null int64
Turn_Bet_S1       39347 non-null float64
Turn_Bet_S2       39347 non-null float64
Turn_Bet_S3       39347 non-null float64
Turn_Bet_S4       39347 non-null float64
Turn_Bet_S5       39347 non-null float64
Turn_Bet_S6       39347 non-null float64
Turn_Raise_S1     39347 non-null object
Turn_Raise_S2     39347 non-null object
Turn_Raise_S3     39347 non-null object
Turn_Raise_S4     39347 non-null object
Turn_Raise_S5     39347 non-null object
Turn_Raise_S6     39347 non-null object
Turn_Call_S1      39347 non-null object
Turn_Call_S2      39347 non-null object
Turn_Call_S3      39347 non-null object
Turn_Call_S4      39347 non-null object
Turn_Call_S5      39347 non-null object
Turn_Call_S6      39347 non-null object
Saw_Turn_S1       39347 non-null int64
Saw_Turn_S2       39347 non-null int64
Saw_Turn_S3       39347 non-null int64
Saw_Turn_S4       39347 non-null int64
Saw_Turn_S5       39347 non-null int64
Saw_Turn_S6       39347 non-null int64
River_Bet_S1      39347 non-null float64
River_Bet_S2      39347 non-null float64
River_Bet_S3      39347 non-null float64
River_Bet_S4      39347 non-null float64
River_Bet_S5      39347 non-null float64
River_Bet_S6      39347 non-null float64
River_Raise_S1    39347 non-null object
River_Raise_S2    39347 non-null object
River_Raise_S3    39347 non-null object
River_Raise_S4    39347 non-null object
River_Raise_S5    39347 non-null object
River_Raise_S6    39347 non-null object
River_Call_S1     39347 non-null object
River_Call_S2     39347 non-null object
River_Call_S3     39347 non-null object
River_Call_S4     39347 non-null object
River_Call_S5     39347 non-null object
River_Call_S6     39347 non-null object
Saw_River_S1      39347 non-null int64
Saw_River_S2      39347 non-null int64
Saw_River_S3      39347 non-null int64
Saw_River_S4      39347 non-null int64
Saw_River_S5      39347 non-null int64
Saw_River_S6      39347 non-null int64
S1_shows?         39347 non-null int64
S2_shows?         39347 non-null int64
S3_shows?         39347 non-null int64
S4_shows?         39347 non-null int64
S5_shows?         39347 non-null int64
S6_shows?         39347 non-null int64
Winner?_S1        39347 non-null int64
Winner?_S2        39347 non-null int64
Winner?_S3        39347 non-null int64
Winner?_S4        39347 non-null int64
Winner?_S5        39347 non-null int64
Winner?_S6        39347 non-null int64
W/L_amount_S1     39347 non-null float64
W/L_amount_S2     39347 non-null float64
W/L_amount_S3     39347 non-null float64
W/L_amount_S4     39347 non-null float64
W/L_amount_S5     39347 non-null float64
W/L_amount_S6     39347 non-null float64
Pot               39347 non-null float64
Rake              39347 non-null float64
```

According to that i set dtypes:

```
dtypes = {'Soft': np.object,
          'Hand_ID': np.int64,
          'Table_Name': np.object,
          'SmallBlind': np.float64,
          'BigBlind': np.float64,
          'Currency': np.object,
          'Day': np.object,
          'Hour': np.object,
          'Seat_1': np.object, 'Seat_2': np.object, 'Seat_3': np.object, 'Seat_4': np.object, 'Seat_5': np.object, 'Seat_6': np.object,
          'Stack_1': np.float64, 'Stack_2': np.float64, 'Stack_3': np.float64, 'Stack_4': np.float64, 'Stack_5': np.float64, 'Stack_6': np.float64,
'Raise_Pre_S1': np.object, 'Raise_Pre_S2': np.object, 'Raise_Pre_S3': np.object, 'Raise_Pre_S4': np.object, 'Raise_Pre_S5': np.object, 'Raise_Pre_S6': np.object,
'Call_Pre_S1': np.object, 'Call_Pre_S2': np.object, 'Call_Pre_S3': np.object, 'Call_Pre_S4': np.object, 'Call_Pre_S5': np.object, 'Call_Pre_S6': np.object,
'Flop_Bet_S1': np.float64, 'Flop_Bet_S2': np.float64, 'Flop_Bet_S3': np.float64, 'Flop_Bet_S4': np.float64, 'Flop_Bet_S5': np.float64, 'Flop_Bet_S6': np.float64,
'Flop_Raise_S1': np.object, 'Flop_Raise_S2': np.object, 'Flop_Raise_S3': np.object, 'Flop_Raise_S4': np.object, 'Flop_Raise_S5': np.object, 'Flop_Raise_S6': np.object,
'Flop_Call_S1': np.object, 'Flop_Call_S2': np.object, 'Flop_Call_S3': np.object, 'Flop_Call_S4': np.object, 'Flop_Call_S5': np.object, 'Flop_Call_S6': np.object, 
'Saw_Flop_S1': np.int64, 'Saw_Flop_S2': np.int64, 'Saw_Flop_S3': np.int64, 'Saw_Flop_S4': np.int64, 'Saw_Flop_S5': np.int64, 'Saw_Flop_S6': np.int64,
'Turn_Bet_S1': np.float64, 'Turn_Bet_S2': np.float64, 'Turn_Bet_S3': np.float64, 'Turn_Bet_S4': np.float64, 'Turn_Bet_S5': np.float64, 'Turn_Bet_S6': np.float64,
'Turn_Raise_S1': np.object, 'Turn_Raise_S2': np.object, 'Turn_Raise_S3': np.object, 'Turn_Raise_S4': np.object, 'Turn_Raise_S5': np.object, 'Turn_Raise_S6': np.object,
'Turn_Call_S1': np.object, 'Turn_Call_S2': np.object, 'Turn_Call_S3': np.object, 'Turn_Call_S4': np.object, 'Turn_Call_S5': np.object, 'Turn_Call_S6': np.float64,
'Saw_Turn_S1': np.int64, 'Saw_Turn_S2': np.int64, 'Saw_Turn_S3': np.int64, 'Saw_Turn_S4': np.int64, 'Saw_Turn_S5': np.int64, 'Saw_Turn_S6': np.int64,
'River_Bet_S1': np.float64,'River_Bet_S2': np.float64,'River_Bet_S3': np.float64,'River_Bet_S4': np.float64,'River_Bet_S5': np.float64,'River_Bet_S6': np.float64,
'River_Raise_S1': np.object, 'River_Raise_S2': np.object,'River_Raise_S3': np.object, 'River_Raise_S4': np.object, 'River_Raise_S5': np.object, 'River_Raise_S6': np.object,
'River_Call_S1': np.object, 'River_Call_S2': np.object, 'River_Call_S3': np.object, 'River_Call_S4': np.object, 'River_Call_S5': np.object, 'River_Call_S6': np.object,
'Saw_River_S1': np.int64,'Saw_River_S2': np.int64,'Saw_River_S3': np.int64,'Saw_River_S4': np.int64,'Saw_River_S5': np.int64, 'Saw_River_S6': np.int64,
'S1_shows?': np.int64, 'S2_shows?': np.int64, 'S3_shows?': np.int64, 'S4_shows?': np.int64, 'S5_shows?': np.int64, 'S6_shows?': np.int64,
'Winner?_S1': np.int64, 'Winner?_S2': np.int64, 'Winner?_S3': np.int64, 'Winner?_S4': np.int64, 'Winner?_S5': np.int64, 'Winner?_S6': np.int64,
'W/L_amount_S1': np.float64, 'W/L_amount_S2': np.float64, 'W/L_amount_S3': np.float64, 'W/L_amount_S4': np.float64, 'W/L_amount_S5': np.float64, 'W/L_amount_S6': np.float64,
'Pot': np.float64,
'Rake': np.float64}
```

and try to read the same csv with this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\AdamPer\Desktop\Python\Magisterka\test2.csv', encoding= "utf_8_sig", dtype=dtypes)
```

and it raise me an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[]'
```

Any ideas how to solve this?
[Link to smaller csv file](https://ufile.io/p7z9069l)

Comment: So how much physical ram do you have? Will this even fit into memory?

Comment: I have 12gb ram and i'm using Python 64bit

Comment: @Ciamciaramcia Do you get the same error even if you use a small chunk of the original .csv file (let's say 100MB)?

Comment: Well that should answer your question then, you either, read in chunks, work on those chunks and write the result out, or look at pyTables see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas. Basically it will not work trying to read this whole file into memory. Besides looking at your last error you have some duff data which you need to sort out

Comment: When i read 16mb csv file with similar data as ~14gb without dtype argument there is no error. When i read either 16mb and 14gb csv with dtype there is the same ValueError: