# Converting large lists of dicts to float32 DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dtype

I am trying to use python to turn binary files into pandas DataFrames for easy subsetting and data analysis. My package works, but only for small files ('small' meaning ~500mb). A workable example of the final bits of the code is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
output = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)   # Memory error occurs here for large files
```

I can reduce the size of the DataFrame by about 40-50% using `.astype('float32')`, but I need the dtype to be set to float32 *before* the DataFrame is built, not afterwards since the memory error occurs during the creation of the DataFrame.
Is there a way of changing the default dtype of pd.DataFrame() to use float32 instead of float64 and int64?

Comment: If you are hitting the memory limit, you should considere processing less data or not using pandas... Any further processing could raise the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas

Comment: How exactly are you reading the data?

Comment: Currently I'm opening the file with `read`, storing a line of information in a dict, appending the dict to a list, then looping to the next line. This gives a list of dicts where each key:value pair in the dict corresponds to a column name and value, and each member of the list corresponds to a row of data. I then call `pd.DataFrame()` on it and specify the columns I want.
The reason I do this is that I need to be able to subset and modify columns of data, as well as extract subsets of columns for fitting and making graphs.