# Pandas dataframe: how to summarize columns containing value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my dataframe:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(
{"mat" : ['A' ,'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
 "ppl" : ['P', 'P', 'P', '',  'P'],
 "ia1" : ['',  'X', 'X', '',  'X'],
 "ia2" : ['X', '',  '',  'X', 'X']},
index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I want to select unique values on the two first columns. I do:

```
df2 = df.loc[:,['mat','ppl']].drop_duplicates(subset=['mat','ppl']).sort_values(by=['mat','ppl'])
```

I get, as expected:

```
  mat ppl
4   A    
1   A   P
5   B   P
```

What I want now is, df3 to be:

```
 mat ppl ia1 ia2
   A           X
   A   P   X   X
   B   P   X   X
```

That is: in `df3` for row A+P, in column ia1, I got an X because there is a X in column ia1 in one of the row of `df`, for A+P

Comment: Actually, very close to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246817/python-pandas-custom-agg-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions with [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) and [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html), if multiple unique values then are joined with `,`:

```
df = df.groupby(['mat','ppl']).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x[x != ''].unique())).reset_index()
print (df)
  mat ppl ia1 ia2
0   A           X
1   A   P   X   X
2   B   P   X   X
```

Explanation:

Aggregation is working with `Series` and aggregation function, where output is scalar. I use custom function where first filter out empty spaces by boolean indexing `(x[x != '']`, then get unique values. For scalar output is used `join` - it works if empty Series (all values are empty strings) and second advantage is if multiple unique values get one joined value with `,`.

For testing is possible use custom function what is same as lambda function:

```
def f(x):
    a = ''.join(x[x != ''].unique().tolist())
    return a

df = df.groupby(['mat','ppl']).agg(f).reset_index()
print (df)
  mat ppl ia1 ia2
0   A           X
1   A   P   X   X
2   B   P   X   X
```

As comment of OP mentioned:

> Instead of using lambda x: ','.join(x[x != ''].unique()), I used lambda x: ','.join(set(x)-set([''])). 
>   I went from 13min 5s to 43.2 s

Comment: Can you please explain the `lambda x: ','.join(x[x != ''].unique())` ?

Comment: Please check answer.

Comment: What I was not understanding is that `x` is representing all columns to aggregate.

Comment: Hmmm, I think if no column is specify like `df = df.groupby(['mat','ppl']).agg({'ia1':f}).reset_index()` or `df = df.groupby(['mat','ppl'])['ia1'].agg(f).reset_index()` then function `agg` use all columns and apply aggreagate function. Btw, thank you.

Comment: Well, this is hugely slow on a dataframe with 100K rows and groupby on 10 columns + 4 columns to aggregate.

Comment: Hmmm, it is really large df and complicated function. I am afraid about it :(

Comment: Instead of using `lambda x: ','.join(x[x != ''].unique())`, I used `lambda x: ','.join(set(x)-set(['']))`. I went from 13min 5s to 43.2 s. @jezrael Can you update answer?

Comment: Good news. Sure. But I am on phone only.